# Does Java have methods to get the various byte order marks?

Tags: java, unicode, byte-order-mark

I am looking for a utility method or constant in Java that will return me the bytes that correspond to the appropriate byte order mark for an encoding, but I can't seem to find one. Is there one?  I really would like to do something like:

```
byte[] bom = Charset.forName( CharEncoding.UTF8 ).getByteOrderMark();
```

Where `CharEncoding` comes from Apache Commons.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835430/byte-order-mark-screws-up-file-reading-in-java/1835529#1835529

Answer (score 4):

Java does not recognize byte order marks for UTF-8. See bugs [4508058](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4508058) and [6378911](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6378911).

The gist is that support was added, broke backwards compatibility, and was rolled back. You'll have to do BOM recognition in UTF-8 yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Apache Commons IO contains what you are looking for, see [`org.apache.commons.io.ByteOrderMark`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/ByteOrderMark.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can generate the BOM like this:

```
byte[] utf8_bom = "\uFEFF".getBytes("UTF-8");
byte[] utf16le_bom = "\uFEFF".getBytes("UnicodeLittleUnmarked");
```

If you wish to create the BOMs for other encodings using this method, make sure you use the version of the encoding that does not automatically insert the BOM or it will be repeated. This technique only applies to Unicode encodings and will not produce meaningful results for others (like Windows-1252).

- [Unicode BOM FAQ](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html)
- [Sun Java 6 supported encodings](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html)
- [Sun Java 5 supported encodings](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html)

Comment: My specific case is writing a CSV file that is UTF-8. As far as I can tell, the UTF-8 BOM is the only way to convince Excel to not attempt to read the file in the default character encoding.

Comment: There isn't a util method that will help you with your Excel file, but writing 0xEF 0xBF 0xBF to your OutputStream shouldn't be a problem. Just flush those bytes before you wrap your stream in a UTF-8 encoded Writer.

Comment: I wouldn't say that "its usage is discouraged" by the FAQ. It is true that the UTF-8 BOM doesn't specify a "byte-order mark" (making it something of a misnomer), but it definitely helps in signifying that the stream uses UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: That's a fair comment - I've updated the post. I can't help feeling they used favour not using it, though: http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/17/2158334.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything in the JDK as far as I can see, nor any of the Apache projects.

Eclipse EMF has an Enum however that provides support:

[`org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.ContentHandler.ByteOrderMark`](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/topic/org.eclipse.emf.doc/references/javadoc/org/eclipse/emf/ecore/resource/ContentHandler.ByteOrderMark.html)

I'm not sure whether that's of any help to you?

There's some more info here on the various BOM's for each encoding type, you could write a simple helper class or enum for this...

http://mindprod.com/jgloss/bom.html

Hope that helps.  I'm surprised this isn't in Commons I/O to be honest.

Comment: It's in there now: http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/BOMInputStream.html

Answer (score 1):

It worth noting that many encodings don't use any byte order marks. e.g. an empty string in UTF-8 is just an empty byte[].  While there is a BOM specified for UTF-8 it is rarely used in Java and is not always supported.

Comment: Downvoted, because this seems to be incorrect as written. A three-byte sequence of bytes containing the UTF-8 BOM (EFBBBF) will be interpreted as an empty UTF-8 string *if* the application understands how to handle BOMs.  (And if it doesn't, the BOM is going to cause trouble, empty string or no.)

Comment: Java doesn't understand BOMs for UTF-8. I've seen people get bit by this (text editor decided to add a BOM, javac puked.)

Comment: Peter's answer is incorrect, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding