# Is there a Java equivalent of the Javascript method fromCharCode()?

Tags: java, javascript, android, eclipse, android-activity

Although I do understand that javascript and Java are very different programming languages, I like the method **fromCharCode ()** with which I can convert a unicode character like 65 to A etc. 
Is there a method within Java which will allow me to do the same?

Example of use fromCharCode() in javascript:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var res = String.fromCharCode(83);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=res;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Cast the integer value to a `char`: `(char) 83` yields `'S'`.

Comment: In Java Use `Character.toString((char)65)` which return `A`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Unicode character from its number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585919/creating-unicode-character-from-its-number)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can cast the integer to char

```
int i = 83;
char c = (char)83;
```

if you want to get the string:

```
String s = Character.toString(c);
```