# Android emoji issue(convert "\uD83D\uDE04" to 0x1F604)

Tags: android, emoji

I can display emoji in textview by this way [how set emoji by unicode in android textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893796/how-set-emoji-by-unicode-in-android-textview) , but how to convert something like "uD83D\uDE04" to the code point 0x1F604("uD83D\uDE04" represent 0x1F604)?

[image]

Comment: See here for details https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates

Answer (score 5):

Do something like this.

**Convert UTF-16 to UTF-8**

```
String text = new String("uD83D\uDE04".getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

**Get the code point**

```
int codepoint = text.codePointAt(0);
```

**Convert it to Unicode**

```
String yourUnicode="U+"+Integer.toHexString(codepoint)
```

Answer (score 1):

I find a way:java.lang.Character.toCodePoint(char high, char low)

```
int ss1 = Integer.parseInt("d83d", 16);
int ss2 = Integer.parseInt("de04", 16);

char chars = Character.toChars(ss1)[0];
char chars2 = Character.toChars(ss2)[0];

int codepoint = Character.toCodePoint(chars, chars2);
String emojiString = new String(Character.toChars(codepoint));
```

Comment: This is just a complicated way of doing `emojiString = "\ud83d\ude04"`

Comment: @Henry You are right.  I just confused this two: String s = "\\ud83d\\ude04";String s = "\ud83d\ude04"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Henry,I find a easy to get emojiString:

```
String ss1 = "d83d";
String ss2 = "de04";
int in1 = Integer.parseInt(ss1, 16);
int in2 = Integer.parseInt(ss2, 16);
String s1 = Character.toString((char)in1);//   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585919/creating-unicode-character-from-its-number
String s2 = Character.toString((char)in2);
String emojiString = s1+s2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by creating this method:

```
fun encodeEmoji(message: String): String {
    try {
        val messageEscape = StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript(message)
        val chars = Character.toChars(
                Integer.parseInt(messageEscape
                        .subSequence(2, 6).toString(), 16))[0]
        val chars2 = Character.toChars(
                Integer.parseInt(messageEscape
                        .subSequence(8, messageEscape.length).toString(), 16))[0]
        val codepoint = Character.toCodePoint(chars, chars2)
        return Integer.toHexString(codepoint)
    } catch (e: UnsupportedEncodingException) {
        return message
    }
}
```