# Encode and Decode Emoji From editText in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to use emoji in my `EditText` Fields. But the problem is that when I try to convert emoji into hexa the value is not correct.

I'm using this function to get emoji value in Hexa.

```
public static String escapeJavaString(String st){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < st.length(); i++) {
            char c = st.charAt(i);
            if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c) && !Character.isSpaceChar(c)&& !Character.isWhitespace(c) ){
                String hexa= String.valueOf(c);
                int code = (int)c;
                if(!(code >= 0 && code <= 255)){
                    hexa= "0x"+Integer.toHexString(c);
                }
                builder.append(unicode);
            }
            else{
                builder.append(c);
            }
        }
        Log.i(TAG, builder.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

I tried to add smiley face and it give me value `0xd83d` Which is not work in below function.

And Here is function to convert Hexa value into Emoji, This function is working fine I tried it with providing manual Hexa value.

```
        // 0xd83d this value is get from above function but not work
        // in this function 
        //String hexaCode = "0xd83d"; // not work
        String hexaCode = "0x1F60A"; // work
        int emoji= Integer.parseInt(hexaCode.substring(2), 16);
        reurn new String(Character.toChars(emoji));
```

Can you please let me know what am I doing wrong. Please don't refer me to any emoji library.

Comment: I thought you are asking for library ,  refer discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45453202/how-to-use-the-imagestored-image-of-device-with-text-on-textview-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it and this is working fine for me.
Here is code.

```
public String escapeJavaString(String st){
    int ss1 = 0,ss2;
    Boolean high = true;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < st.length(); i++) {
            char c = st.charAt(i);
            if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c) && !Character.isSpaceChar(c)&& !Character.isWhitespace(c) ){
                String unicode = String.valueOf(c);
                int code = (int)c;
                if(!(code >= 0 && code <= 255)){
                    unicode = Integer.toHexString(c);
                    if(high){
                        high = false;
                        ss1 = Integer.parseInt(unicode, 16);
                    }else{
                        high = true;
                        ss2 = Integer.parseInt(unicode, 16);
                        char chars = Character.toChars(ss1)[0];
                        char chars2 = Character.toChars(ss2)[0];
                        int codepoint = Character.toCodePoint(chars, chars2);
                        unicode = "Ax" + codepoint;
                        builder.append(unicode);
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                builder.append(c);
            }
        }
        Log.i(TAG, builder.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

And For decoding use this.

```
    int emoji= Integer.parseInt(hexaCode.substring(2));
    reurn new String(Character.toChars(emoji));
```

Answer (score 0):

In `escapeJavaString(String st)` method you are getting unicode. You can't convert it to codePonit just adding `0x` at start. Take a look at [this aswer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835966/android-emoji-issueconvert-ud83d-ude04-to-0x1f604), hope you find a key

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = edText.getText().toString();
String unicodeStr = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(str);
```

You can get Unicode from emoji by using commons-lang-2.5 jar

if you want to get index or hex value then first need to parse a string into HTML characters

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml()
```

or use an emoji4j library.

For example:

```
String line = "Hi , i am fine \uD83D\uDE02 \uD83D\uDE02, how r u ?";
EmojiUtils.hexHtmlify(line); //Hi , i am fine &#x1f602; &#x1f602;, how r u ?
```

here 1f602 is your hex code.

```
System.out.println(Character.toChars(Integer.parseInt("1f602",16)));
```