# Reading unicode char codes JAVA

Tags: java, unicode

Hi I'm reading [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t081nAstVILJaWt3EbtO5RiiSY8wcX6w/view?usp=sharing) (please, use the link to see the file) that contains this rows:

```
U+0000
U+0001
U+0002
U+0003
U+0004
U+0005
```

using this code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;

 public class fgenerator {    
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try(BufferedReader br  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:\\UNCDUNCD.txt")))){
        String line;
        String[] splited;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            splited = line.split(" ");
            System.out.println(splited[0]);
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

but output is

```
U+D01C
U+D01D
U+D01E
U+D01F
U+D020
U+D021
```

1. why does this happen?
2. how to get the char of its code

Comment: When I run this I get `U+0000
U+0001
U+0002
U+0003
U+0004
U+0005`

Comment: Your question is confusing.  If printing the entire line shows the six characters `U+D01C`, then the line obviously contains those six characters.  I’m not clear on whether you believe each line contains six ASCII characters, or a single Unicode codepoint.

Comment: Taking your code and wrapping it up into a full class with a `main` method, I get the output, like GBlodgett says, of exactly what the file contains. You say your input is `U+0000` etc. but your output is `U+D01C` etc. _I do not get that result._ I _believe_ your input is `U+D01C` and your output is `U+D01C`, and I further assume that what you want is to read `U+D01C` and output the _Unicode Character_ at code-point D01C. (by the way, there is no character there "U+D01C is not a valid unicode character" according to fileformat.info)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Unicode character from its number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585919/creating-unicode-character-from-its-number)

Comment: What you want to do is take the string you read in, such as `U+25C0`, strip off the "U+" part and turn the rest `25C0` into an int: e.g. `Integer.parseInt("25C0", 16);`. At that point the question becomes "[Creating Unicode character from its number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5585919/17300)"

Answer (score 0):

change line datatype to `char`, if doesnt work then `String.getBytes()`

Comment: `BufferedReader.readLine()` returns a `String` **not** a `char` - so if you changed `String line;` into `char line;` it wouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to take the Unicode *representation* that is on each line of the file and output the actual Unicode *character* which the code represents.

If we start with your loop that reads each line from the file...

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){             
    System.out.println( line );
}
```

... then what we want to do is *convert* the input `line` to the character, and print *that* ...

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){             
    System.out.println( convert(line) ); <- I just put a method call to "convert()"
}
```

So, how do you `convert(line)` into a character before printing it?
As my earlier comment suggested, you want to take the numeric string that follows the `U+` and convert it to an actual numeric value. That, then, is the character value you want to print.

The following is a complete program — essentially like yours but I take the filename as an argument rather than hard-coding it.  I've also added skipping blank lines, and rejecting invalid strings -- printing a blank space instead.

Reject the line if it does not match the `U+nnnn` form of a Unicode representation — match against `"(?i)U\\+[0-9A-F]{4}"`, which means:
`(?i)` - ignore case
`U\\+` - match `U+`, where the `+` has to be escaped to be a literal plus
`[0-9A-F]` - match any character 0-9 or A-F (ignoring case)
`{4}` - exactly 4 times

---

With your update that includes a linked sample file, which includes `#` comments, I have modified my original program (below) so it will now strip comments and then convert the remaining representation.

This is a complete program that can be run as:
`javac Reader2.java`
`java Reader2 inputfile.txt`

I tested it with a subset of your file, starting *inputfile.txt* at line 1 with `U+0000` and ending at line 312 with `U+0138`

```
import java.io.*;

public class Reader2
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        final String filename = args[0];
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                                    new FileReader(new File( filename ))
                                 )
            )
        {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.trim().length() > 0) { // skip blank lines
                  //System.out.println( convert(line) );
                  final Character c = convert(line);
                  if (Character.isValidCodePoint(c)) {
                        System.out.print  ( c );
                  }
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static char convert(final String input)
    {
        //System.out.println("Working on line: " + input);
        if (! input.matches("(?i)U\\+[0-9A-F]{4}(\\s+#.*)")) {
            System.err.println("Rejecting line: " + input);
            return ' ';
        }
        else {
            //System.out.println("Accepting line: " + input);
        }
        // else
        final String stripped = input.replaceFirst("\\s+#.*$", "");
        final Integer cval = Integer.parseInt(stripped.substring(2), 16);
        //System.out.println("cval = " + cval);
        return (char) cval.intValue();
    }
}
```

---

**Original program that assumed a line consisted *only* of `U+nnnn` is here.**

You would run this as:
`javac Reader.java`
`java Reader input.txt`

```
import java.io.*;

public class Reader
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        final String filename = args[0];
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                                    new FileReader(new File( filename ))
                                 )
            )
        {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.trim().length() > 0) { // skip blank lines
                  //System.out.println( line );
                    // Write all chars on one line rather than one char per line
                    System.out.print  ( convert(line) );
                }
            }
            System.out.println(); // Print a newline after all chars are printed
        }
        catch(Exception e) {      // don't catch plain `Exception` IRL
            e.printStackTrace();  // don't just print a stack trace IRL
        }
    }

    private static char convert(final String input)
    {
        // Reject any line that doesn't match U+nnnn
        if (! input.matches("(?i)U\\+[0-9A-F]{4}")) {
            System.err.println("Rejecting line: " + input);
            return ' ';
        }
        // else convert the line to the character
        final Integer cval = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(2), 16);
        //System.out.println("cval = " + cval);
        return (char) cval.intValue();
    }
}
```

Try it using this as your input file:

```
U+0041
bad line
U+2718
U+00E9
u+0073
```

Redirect standard error when you run it `java Reader input.txt 2> /dev/null` or comment out the line `System.err.println...`
You should get this output: **A ✘és**

Comment: My question has to aspects.
1. I'm reading file that contains 
U+0020
U+0021
U+0022
U+0023
............
but when I'm printing the lines console shows this
U+D01C
U+D01D
U+D01E
U+D01F
why is so?
2. how convert whatever I have to it's char representation?

Comment: @Arno — everybody (in the comments) is reporting that, when they run your code, they get the output that matches the input; that is, `U+0000`, `U+0001` produces `U+0000`, `U+0001` -- it does **not** produce `U+D01C`, `U+D01D` as you say. (and your original question says you are reading `U+0000`, **not** that you are reading `U+0020` as you say here). Nobody (including me) has been able to reproduce what you say is happening. What happens if you compile and run the full standalone program that I have provided? Can you provide a full standalone program that reproduces what you say is happening?