# How to display illegal characters on downloaded file name in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

My downloaded file name becomes **Ça_r_lar_02_07_2019_12_09.xlsx**, however, I want it **Çağrılar_02_07_2019_12_09.xlsx**. How Can I fix it?

```
try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
                new XlsExporter().exportXls(workbook, grh);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("_dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm");
                String name = grh.getReportName() + sdf.format(new Date());
                response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM.getType());
                response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + name +  ".xlsx\"");
                workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());
                response.getOutputStream().flush();
            }
```

Comment: And you are sure that the underlying file system (operating system) supports these characters in file names?!

Comment: @GhostCat Yes, it supports

Comment: Have you tried coding your name variable directly with the corresponding unicode charcater as shown here? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585919/creating-unicode-character-from-its-number/5598346  For example your c should be u00c7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try UTF-8 encoding for your filename before sending the response

```
try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
                new XlsExporter().exportXls(workbook, grh);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("_dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm");
                String name = grh.getReportName() + sdf.format(new Date());
                name = URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8"); 
                response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM.getType());
                response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + name +  ".xlsx\"");
                workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());
                response.getOutputStream().flush();
            }
```

Comment: This is correct, as by the HTTP standard the header lines sent before the actual content are in ISO-8859-1.

Comment: blank becomes "+" character, do u know why it is?

Comment: That is because of URL encoding. You can append ```.replaceAll("\\+", "%20")``` to your URLEncoder function. Or use URI class (or URIUtils in Spring) which use RFC 2396. More info can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding