# Integer Object (Unicode) to Characterobject

Tags: java, integer, character

:)I am pretty new to coding! My question is as following:

I have a method which gets a Integer Object i as a parameter and this Integer is supposed to be a Unicode. Now my question is, is there a way to transform a given Unicode to a Characterobject?
A little example to illustrate the question:

```
public Character randomName(Integer i) {
    if(i == 0)
            throw new NullPointerException();
    if(i > Character.MAX_VALUE)
            throw new FormatException(i);
    else {
            Character c = new Character(i);
            return c;
}
```

of course this doesn't work but i can't find a way around it....
Downcasting didnt work and I usually use char and int but in this case i have to do it that way.

Thanks for the help already!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating Unicode character from its number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585919/creating-unicode-character-from-its-number)

Comment: It certainly helped, still, as the return type is a single Character Object I still dont know how to turn the integer into a Character but thanks a lot, it helped already a little!

Comment: Note that a Character/char can't hold all possible Unicode codepoints.

Comment: But if that's not a problem, `return Character.vakueOf((char) i.intValue());`

Comment: thanks! seems to work so far:)

Comment: is there a way around using a downcast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a `Character` object represents a `char`;  i.e. a number on the range `0` through `0xffff`.  Unicode code-points range up to `U+10FFFF` and many cannot be represented as a single `char` value.

So this gives you a problem:

- If the code-points that you want to represent are all between `U+0000` and `U+FFFF`, then you can represent them as `Character` values.
- If any are `U+10000` or larger, then it won't work.

So, if you have an `int` that represents a Unicode code-point, you need to do  do something like this:

```
int value = ...

if (Character.isDefined(value)) {
    if (value <= 0xffff) {
        return Character.valueOf((char) value);
    } else {
        // code point not representable as a `Character`
    }
} else {
    // Not a valid code-point at all
}
```

Note:

1. `int` values that are not valid code points *include* negative values, values greater than `0x10ffff` and lower and upper surrogate code-units.
2. A number of commonly used Unicode code-points are great than U+10000.  For example, the code-points for Emojis!  This means that using `Character` is a **bad idea**.  It would be better to use either a `String`, a `char[]` or an `Integer`.

---

> It seems to work so far.

I guess you haven't tried @Shawn's approach with an Emoji yet.

> Is there a way around using a downcast?

No.

> ```
> if(i == 0)
>        throw new NullPointerException();
> ```

That is just wrong:

1. Zero is a valid code-point.
2. Even if it wasn't valid, it is NOT a `null`.  So throwing `NullPointerException` is totally inappropriate.
3. If you are concerned about the case where `i` is `null`, don't worry.  Any operation that unboxes `i` will *automatically* throw `NullPointerException` if it is `null`.  Just let it happen ...

Comment: Wow, thanks! Well, my method is supposed to throw exceptions if the value is e.g negative or out of the Character's Max Value. So, it only turns the integer into a char after it checked if it is even possible. Yes a String would also be a lot easier but my task clearly wants a Charakter..... Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Sounds like your task is incorrect!  But I guess there are few people who teach Java and don't understand Unicode properly.