# JavaFX string to unicode entity conversion

Tags: java, unicode, unicode-normalization

I have to read a string from a file and display the corresponding unicode representation in a Text field on my application.

For example I read the string "e13a" from the file and i'd like to display the corresponding "\ue13a" character in the Text field.

Is there a way to obtain the desired behaviour?

I already tried escaping the string directly in the file but I always obtain the raw string instead of the unicode representation

Comment: So you want the character ``? Your Question is not clear; I suggest editing for clarity.

Comment: JavaFX seems irrelevant here. If so, delete mentions and tag.  If not, explain.

Comment: Please see the answers to question [Creating Unicode character from its number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5585919/2985643). Do none of the answers there offer a solution to your problem?

Comment: Thank you @skomisa. I didn’t find that answer!

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
Character.toString( Integer.parseInt( "e13a" , 16 ) )
```

See this code run [at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/Fu7Jfl).

> 

## Code point

Parse your input string as a [hexadecimal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) number, base 16. Convert to a decimal number, base 10.

That number represents a [code point](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point), the number permanently assigned to each of the over 144,000 characters defined in Unicode. Code points range from zero to just over one million, with most of that range unassigned.

```
String input = "e13a" ; 
int codePoint = Integer.parseInt( input , 16 ) ;
```

Instantiate a `String` object whose content is the character identified by that code point.

```
String output = Character.toString( codePoint ) ;
```

> 

## Avoid `char`

The `char` type has been essentially broken since Java 2, and legacy since Java 5. As a 16-bit value, `char` is physically incapable of representing most characters.

To work with individual characters, use code point integers as seen above.

Comment: Why answer this question when it is an obvious duplicate of [Creating Unicode character from its number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5585919/2985643)?

Answer (score 0):

I posted the question after a lot of trying and searching.
Shortly after posting I found a more trivial solution than I expected:

The converted string is:

```
String converted = String.valueOf((char) Integer.parseInt(unicodeString,16));
```

where "unicodeString" is the string I read from the file.

Comment: This code fails with most characters. For example, the FACE WITH MEDICAL MASK emoji character, U+1F637, . See failure [at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/pth4UU).