# Working with special characters derived from a filename in a zip file

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, zip

This question concerns a Tomcat 7 web application, which is connected to a MySQL (5.5.16) database.

When I open a `zip` file, That has filenames encoded in `windows-1252` charset, the characters seem to be interpreted correctly by Java:

```
ZipFile zf = new ZipFile( zipFile, Charset.forName( "windows-1252" ) );
Enumeration entries = zf.entries();
while( entries.hasMoreElements() ) {
    ZipEntry ze = ( ZipEntry ) entries.nextElement();
    if( ! ze.isDirectory() ) {
        String name = ze.getName();
        System.out.println( name ); //prints correct filenames, e.g. café.pdf
    }
}
```

**Omitting the Charset object in the ZipFile constructor would cause an exception**.
The filenames in the zip file are printed correctly to standard output, including diacritics.
But, when I subsequently try to store the filename in a database, the e-acute is replaced with a question mark (as seen with the mysql console client).
I had no problems inserting special characters from the web application into MySQL before.

When I execute an INSERT with `é` in Java source code:

```
statement.executeUpdate( "insert into files (filename) values ('café.pdf')" );
```

the `é` shows up well in MySQL.

Also, my log file shows a comma instead of `é: caf‚.pfd`

Does anyone know what could be happening here?

Comment: How do you open the connection to the MySQL server? What classes/libraries/services do you use?

Comment: To connect Java with MySQL I use a javax.sql.DataSource resource with: driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/workflow?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"

Comment: Please, execute the following query from your Java app. and show us the output: `show variables like 'char%'`

Comment: show variables like 'char%' output:
character_set_client - latin1
character_set_connection - latin1
character_set_database - latin1
character_set_filesystem - binary
character_set_result - 
character_set_server - latin1
character_set_system - utf-8
character_sets_dir - c:\xampp\mysql\share\charsets\

Comment: Is it empty? Can you run the same from your mysql client?

Comment: It's not empty, I hit the enter key accidentally... Most character sets are latin1, except character_set_system which is utf-8, and character_set_filesystem, which is binary. Run from the mysql client the output is different: some sets are cp850.

Comment: Is there any reasons you need to have file names in zip in windows-1252? JDBC+MySQL is always a painful thing when it comes to character sets. You would be way better off, just using utf8 everywhere. Or do you really need to have those file names in win.-1252?

Comment: Yes, the zip files come from different sources and thus could be any character set (which is another problem). Anyway, thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved. [This post](https://blogs.oracle.com/xuemingshen/entry/non_utf_8_encoding_in) suggested that the encoding of filenames in a `zip` file might not be `windows-1252` but rather `IBM437`. Changing the `Charset` from:

```
ZipFile zf = new ZipFile( zipFile, Charset.forName( "windows-1252" ) );
```

to

```
ZipFile zf = new ZipFile( zipFile, Charset.forName( "IBM437" ) );
```

gave the desired result: when saving the acquired filename in MySQL, it was stored correctly with é.

What went wrong?

Printing out the filenames contained in the zip file to standard output with

```
System.out.println( name );
```

made me wrongly assume that the filenames in the zip file were interpreted well: when I used `windows-1252` encoding to open the zip file, the filename was printed to standard output nicely with diacritic: café.pdf. Using other character encodings, different symbols appeared instead of the é.

But when printing the `Unicode` value of the é-`char` with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2220476/824957), I was able to see that when opening the zip file with `windows-1252` encoding, the actual Unicode value was NOT `\u00e9` (latin small letter e with acute), but `\u201a` (single low-9 quotation mark). When I opened the `ZipFile` with `IBM437` charset the correct Unicode value DID appear.

Of course when printing a `String` to standard output with `PrintStream`, the `PrintStream` is also associated with a certain character encoding. From the `PrintStream` Javadoc:

> All characters printed by a PrintStream are converted into bytes using the platform's default character encoding.

I am working on Windows XP.
When I created a new `PrintStream`

```
out = new PrintStream( System.out, true, "IBM437" );
```

everything made sense: opening the zip file with `IBM437` character encoding, and using the new PrintStream, é was printed correctly.

[There Ain't No Such Thing As Plain Text.](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in the comments section, the incoming data (zipped files' names) can be in *different* character sets. This is going to be an issue to you, because you are using MySQL+JDBC link, and it gives you a lot of limitations (like one character set per column in MySQL, and only one character set per connection in JDBC).

Therefore, I would recommend you to switch the character sets (look for variables like `character_set_server` and `character_set_connection`) on the MySQL side to UTF8, because it will enable you to transfer and store almost any character that you may receive. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset.html) on how to properly set up your MySQL server. Note, that settings the MySQL server might be challenging, so don't hesitate to PM for additional help. JDBC will automatically adjust to the server's `character_set_connection` variable, so you don't have to change anything in your Java application.

The one thing you WILL have to change in your application is you would have to convert all incoming data to UTF8 in order to send and store it on the MySQL server.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In the table where you store the data, make sure you use the correct collation to be able to store the e-acute character

Comment: He said that a direct query succeeds, which means that everything is alright on the server's side.