# Encoding pinyin

Tags: java, encode, pinyin

I'm currently developing a program in java, and I want to display Chinese pinyin, which I get from a distant website.

But I have the following problem: Chinese pinyin is displayed this way: `ji&#462;`
Whereas it should be displayed this way: jiǎ
(I just typed the same sequence, except I stripped the slashes).

I think the answer to this question is really simple but I'm struggling to find it.

Comment: How are you fetching the encoded string and how are you displaying it?

Comment: With URL, InputStream and then BufferedReader. But even I think the problem can be solved after, because if I type "j i & # 4 6 2 ;" on google (without the slashes), it displays correctly. I think I'm missing something like escaped characters

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/java-how-to-decode-html-character-entities-in-java-like-httputility-htmldecode

Comment: Using Simplified Chinese in a string literal like this: `System.out.println("pīnyīn jiǎ");` seems to work.  String in Java are all unicode so you don't need to encode them, I think @nhahtdh's comment will lead you in the right direction

Comment: You can actually write code if it is all numbered entities, but if there are named entities, then I recommend you to use existing library to do the job.

Comment: Like this `System.out.println("ji\u01ce");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have an HTML encoded Unicode character and what you want is the decoded version of it.  A library like [commons-lang3](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) (part of Apache Commons) will take your HTML encoded string and decode it for Java to display like this:

```
String decoded = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml("ji&#462;");
```

You can also escape Unicode characters in Java like this:

```
String jia = "ji\u01ce";
```

This clever [one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2220476/16959) will take a Unicode character and show you its escaped form:

```
System.out.println( "\\u" + Integer.toHexString('ǎ' | 0x10000).substring(1) );
```