# Java Unicode to hex string

Tags: java, unicode, printstream

The code below gives me the Unicode string as **கா**

```
sysout = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
sysout.println("\u0B95\u0bbe");
```

By giving **கா** as input, can I get the hex values as **\u0B95** and **\u0bbe**?

PS: This is Tamil language.

Comment: It is not a duplicate I guess. The solution is for single char. But கா is combination of two char. That is why you have two hex values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220366/get-unicode-value-of-a-character) you'll have to try

```
System.out.println( "\\u" + Integer.toHexString('க' | 0x10000).substring(1) );
```

but it will only work on Unicode up to 3.0. If you want to get more values, just create a loop, e.g.

```
String foo = "கா";
for (int i = 0; i < foo.length(); i++)
    System.out.println( "\\u" + Integer.toHexString(foo.charAt(i) | 0x10000).substring(1));
```

which produces

```
\u0b95
\u0bbe
```

If you want to have them in one line, change `System.out.println()` to `System.out.print()` and add `System.out.print("\n")` in the end.

Comment: Actually i need the hex string of "கா" and not "க". they both are different.

Comment: @Mateusz I want the same thing in an opposite way, how can achieve it?

Comment: @SantoshJadi try `int val = 0x0B95;
        String str = Character.toString((char) val);`

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) functionality to print the Java UTF-16 string escapes.

For example, this code writes the escapes to STDOUT:

```
String str = "கா";
for(char ch : str.toCharArray())
   System.out.format("\\u%04x", (int) ch);
```