# How to test for Greek Letters in java

Tags: java, unicode

So my program requires me to test for the greek letter delta. I've found the unicode value \u0394 that translates to δ. But the statement does not run, meaning it does not read the delta. Here getXunit returns the String value of the Unit, which should be delta, but when printed it returns ?.

```
if(getSpectrum().getXUnit().equals("\u03B4"){
  //do stuff
}
```

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean "does not work"?  Does it crash?  Does it just fail to detect equals?  Does it set fire to your living room furniture?

Comment: What are `getSpectrum()` and `getXUnit()`? Most importantly, what is the return type of `getXUnit()`?

Comment: getXUnit returns a String. And does not work, means it does not detect the delta in the XUnit. When I print XUnit, it returns ?, when I can see the delta on the spectrum.

Comment: Unless `getXunit()` returns a string containing the single character `\u0394` this code won't work.

Comment: Small delta is 03*B*4. Also there's a delta in the latin area, 1E9F. 0394 would be capital delta, but you supposedly were not looking for that.

Comment: One thing you could check, is the unicode value of the particular delta you need, using the tricks here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220366/get-unicode-value-of-a-character . Another possible problem source is if the file (?) you get the data from is read using a wrong encoding.