# Print the unicode code instead of character

Tags: java, unicode, output

I would like eclipse to allow to print and save a unicode code instead of the character (For use in another program after).

```
String string = "\u2588";
```

I want the output to be \u2588 not the block character.

First time posting so sorry for anything done wrong :(.

Comment: See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

Comment: Try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220366/get-unicode-value-of-a-character

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String string = "\\u2588";
```

If you use two backslashes it does not try to detect the [escape sequence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

Answer (score 3):

The backslash `\` is an [escape character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html), to print an actual `'\'` use `"\\"`

```
String s = "\\u2588"
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this code for printing unicode char

```
String unicodeMessage =
        "\u7686\u3055\u3093\u3001\u3053\u3093\u306b\u3061\u306f";

        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
        out.println(unicodeMessage);
```