# How to get a char input and transform it to unicode and print it(Java)

Tags: java, unicode

```
char c = '3';
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println((int)c);
```

The problem that I'm having is getting the input of the `char` and turning it to unicode.
Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "transforming into unicode"; do you want to obtain the code point? Also, remember that a `char` is a UTF-16 code unit, so only code points inside the BMP fit into a single `char`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220366/get-unicode-value-of-a-character

Answer (score 1):

You can use, for instance, [`Character.toCodePoint()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toCodePoint-char-char-).

For code points inside the BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane; code points from U+0000 to U+FFFF), the first argument to this method will always be 0. Note that the reverse operation is [`Character.toChars()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toChars-int-).

Answer (score 0):

I dont't understand what you want on the output, unicode code of symbol or something else? 
And also in Java all symbols are in Unicode :
[Refer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/unicode.html)

Comment: a program that takes a char( for example the letter a and it gives the number that it stands for in unicode : &#97 
http://unicode-table.com/en/#0061

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Please use the 'add a comment' button next time ([SO help about comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)) if you want clarification on the question.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `Character.hashCode(char value)`.

Comment: Conforming Java implementation can do almost anything in this function, including always returning zero.

Comment: @KarolS I was thinking that it always return Unicode for characters