# Convert special Characters to Unicode Escape Characters Scala

Tags: scala, unicode, properties, unicode-escapes

Hello is it possible to convert special Characters like Ä, Ö, Ü, ... to Unicode Escape Characters?
Like **Ä** would be **\u00C4**
I need this to convert a File for Translation purposes. I have a key value pair of Translations on Server Side e.g.:

```
hometown = München
```

and want to parse it to de.properties to use it in my Javascript App.
.properties is by definiton ISO/IEC 8859-1 encoded http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties
So i have to parse the Key/Value Pair to:

```
hometown = M\u00FCnchen
```

Is it possible to get these Escape Characters with Scala/Java?
**EDIT:**
[Get unicode value of a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220366/get-unicode-value-of-a-character) doesnt work for me. E.G. for Character **Ä** i get **\u017D** but i need to get **\u00C4**
**EDIT TO MY EDIT:**
Ah ok the problem was that i tried it on the Scala REPL. When i try

```
println( "\\u" + Integer.toHexString('Ä' | 0x10000).substring(1) )
```

it prints the correct escape character **\u00C4**

Comment: Here: similiar question for Java:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220366/get-unicode-value-of-a-character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than manually trying to do the escaping, use the tools the JVM gives you for working with .properties files. E.g. make an instance of the `Properties` you want, and then use [Properties#store](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store-java.io.OutputStream-java.lang.String-), which will handle the escaping for you.

Response to edit: If you are getting out `\u017D` then you don't have an `Ä` - check your project source encoding and the encoding settings for anywhere you read data.

Comment: Properties class is a really good hint! The only problem, it doesn't Escape ÄÖÜ. I tried to store it like that: prop.store(writer, "DoIt").

Comment: Hmm, interesting - it does escape those on my system. Maybe the reason it doesn't escape ÄÖÜ for you is that those have perfectly good ISO-8859-1 (sometimes called "latin1" but this term is ambiguous) codepoints?

Comment: AHH OK the **store(Writer writer, String comments)** Method doesn't escape, but the **store(OutputStream out, String comments)** does!