# Convert string to unicode

Tags: java, android, unicode, char

i want convert a simple text like, "my simple text" to Unicode character in Android.

for example this :

> "\u0628\u0631\u0646\u0627\u0645\u0647 \u0646\u0648\u06cc\u0633\u06cc"

this string in uni code is :

> برنامه نویسی

i want input

> برنامه نویسی

and response

> "\u0628\u0631\u0646\u0627\u0645\u0647 \u0646\u0648\u06cc\u0633\u06cc"

this string . please help me .

Comment: Have you already tried anything?

Comment: You are mixing a lot of concepts here... What is the initial content of your text file? What encoding does it use?

Comment: are you getting those string from database or edittext?

Comment: Check Oracle [StringConverter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/examples/StringConverter.java) and [UnicodeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/examples/UnicodeFormatter.java)

Comment: what is wrong to just return the `byte[]` representation of the input?

Comment: I would not say that it is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145681/how-to-convert-a-string-with-unicode-encoding-to-a-string-of-letters .. In real it is inverse of that defect, OP wants to achieve opposite of what is talked in that defect .. Now, arguing that do reverse of that is not a rational argument ..

Comment: Yassin Hajaj ; yes i do anything. 

helldawg13 ; use Edittext.

nafas ; how ?!

hagrawal; my question was different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Android native its java, so.. check this:

You can do it for any Java char using the one liner here:

```
System.out.println( "\\u" + Integer.toHexString('÷' | 0x10000).substring(1) );
```

Reference: [Get unicode value of a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220366/get-unicode-value-of-a-character)

I hope that I have helped answer some of your questions.

Comment: i's work. tank you .

Comment: @Stanislav another question: How can I get the utf8 a character

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache Commons Lang api. StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava() can help you get the answer.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;

public class StringUnicode {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String foreignText = "برنامه نویسی";

        String response = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(foreignText);
        System.out.println(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: not work. Please explain one example. tnx

Comment: @MasoudGolmohammadi, added.