# Check if a grouping separator is a space

Tags: java, char, locale, separator

I am trying to check wether a grouping separator (`char`) is a space or not. It's the case for the french locale but my test always prints `false`.

```
DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("fr"));
char ch = formatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator();
System.out.println(ch == ' '); // false
System.out.println(Character.isWhitespace(ch)); // false
```

Comment: So what character is it?

Comment: I don't know, When I print it or inspect it in debug, it's a space.

Comment: To see the unicode value of a char try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220366/get-unicode-value-of-a-character

Comment: Thank you, it will be helpful for sure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The unicode symbol you receive is not a **normal whitespace**. It's a **no-break space**. Your char has the integer representation of **160** not **32**.
To check that you should use:

```
Character.isSpaceChar(ch);
```

That method checks if a character is a space according to the unicode standard.

The following method checks if a charactre is a space according to Java specification.

```
Character.isWhitespace(ch);
```

A detailed description of the criteria can be found at the documentations.

Comment: Oh, nice. How did you find that?

Comment: @CharlesFollet: Quite simple: System.out.println((int)ch); The 160 confused me as the white space should be at least within ASCII range. So I took a look at a unicode table. Did not know that there are such spaces before either. If the answer helps you please accept it

Comment: @CharlesFollet Would you accept the answer so other people know that this helped?

Answer (score 0):

The grouping character is not space, but 160. This will output true and true

```
    DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("fr"));
    char ch = formatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator();
    System.out.println(ch == 160); 
    System.out.println(Character.isSpaceChar(ch));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's non-breaking space

`getGroupingSeparator()`return non-breaking-space. so you can check it with specific unicode of non-breaking-space.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("fr"));
    char ch = formatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator();
    System.out.println(formatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator() == '\u00A0'); // true
    System.out.println(ch == ' '); // false
    System.out.println(Character.isWhitespace(ch)); // false
}
```