# Creating a HashMap using unicode in java

Tags: java, unicode-string

I would like to create a map with japanese character. eg,

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("あ","ア");
    map.put("え","イ");
    map.put("お","オ");
    map.put("え","エ");
    map.put("お","オ");
    String str = "あaいiうuえeおo";
```

Result = アaイiウuエeオo

But I want to put only unicode for japanese characters and I want to compare input string with key of map, then change it to respective value.
How do I change each letter of String str to unicode.
How do I compare each letter in a String with keys of a Map using unicode? 
If each letter exists as a key of the map, change it with respective map value.
Thanks.

Comment: If I am parsing things correctly, I think you can use the Unicode code points instead of the characters. The codepoints are the values like `U+0000`. Also see [Unicode Codepoint Chart](http://inamidst.com/stuff/unidata/).

Comment: Thanks for advice. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each of the keys in your map and call String#replaceAll() for each of the respective keys and values.

As for turning the resulting value into unicode you can view this post: [Get unicode value of a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220366/get-unicode-value-of-a-character).

Comment: String#replaceAll() replaces all the letters. I just want to replace only the letter which includes in key of map. Anyway, Thanks :D