# Reading UTF-8 - BOM marker

Tags: java, file, encoding

I'm reading a file through a FileReader - the file is UTF-8 decoded (with BOM) now my problem is: I read the file and output a string, but sadly the BOM marker is outputted too. Why this occurs?

```
fr = new FileReader(file);
br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String tmp = null;
    while ((tmp = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String text;    
    text = new String(tmp.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    content += text + System.getProperty("line.separator");
}
```

output after first line

```
?<style>
```

Comment: UTF-8 is not supposed to have a BOM!  It is neither necessary **nor recommended** by The Unicode Standard.

Comment: @tchrist: At Microsoft, they do not care about standards.

Comment: To expand on Matti's point, all MS text editors prefix UTF-8 documents with a BOM.

Comment: @Matti "not recommended" != non-standard

Comment: @tchrist tell that to the people who put the BOM in the UTF-8 files (=Microsoft) when saving them.

Comment: @dstibbe I am not responsible for Microsoft’s stupidity. I will have no part in it. My hands are clean.

Comment: @tchrist I wish things were that simple. You create an application for the users, not for yourself. And the users use (partially) Microsoft software to create their files.

Comment: BOM is necessary for UTF-16, optional for UTF-8. Java can handle neither (by standard library). C# can handle both. Now talk who follows standard and who does not.

Comment: @peenut, Java *can* handle BOMs in UTF-16, if you tell it to

Comment: possible duplicate of [Byte order mark screws up file reading in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835430/byte-order-mark-screws-up-file-reading-in-java)

Comment: @tchriist, BOM is a standard - not from MS or Unicode. peenut is right, that the BOM for UTF-16 in xml files is a MUST and UTF-8 BOM in xml file is a may. xml Standard at W3org https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charencoding. The methods for autodetection of the BOM is a none normative standard. Section >F Autodetection of Character Encodings (Non-Normative)<

Answer (score 97, accepted):

In Java, you have to consume manually the UTF8 BOM if present. This behaviour is documented in the Java bug database, [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4508058) and [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6378911). There will be no fix for now because it will break existing tools like JavaDoc or XML parsers. The [Apache IO Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/input/BOMInputStream.html) provides a `BOMInputStream` to handle this situation.

Comment: Very late to the game, but this seems to be very slow for large files. I tried using a buffer. If you use a buffer, it seems to leave some sort of trailing data, as well.

Answer (score 52):

The easiest fix is probably just to remove the resulting `\uFEFF` from the string, since it is extremely unlikely to appear for any other reason.

```
tmp = tmp.replace("\uFEFF", "");
```

Also see [this Guava bug report](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=345&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Summary)

Comment: The bad thing about "extremely unlikely" is that it turns up extremely rarely, so that locating the bug is extremely difficult... :) So be extremely wary when using this code if you believe your software will be successful and long-lived, because sooner or later any existing situation will occur.

Comment: `FEFF` is a UTF-16 BOM.  The UTF-8 BOM is `EFBBBF`.

Comment: @StevePitchers but we must match it *after* decoding, when it is part of a `String` (which is always represented as UTF-16)

Comment: What about `\uFFFE` (UTF-16, little-endian)?

Comment: @live-love And if the file doesn't have a BOM, you just truncated the first line.

Comment: To make sure you only replace the BOM if it's right at the beggining of the string, you could use `tmp = tmp.replaceAll("\\A\uFEFF", "");`

Comment: What's wrong with replacing it only if it's at the start of the file instead of anywhere in it ?

Answer (score 40):

Use the [Apache Commons library](https://commons.apache.org/io/).

Class: [`org.apache.commons.io.input.BOMInputStream`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/input/BOMInputStream.html)

Example usage:

```
String defaultEncoding = "UTF-8";
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(someFileWithPossibleUtf8Bom);
try {
    BOMInputStream bOMInputStream = new BOMInputStream(inputStream);
    ByteOrderMark bom = bOMInputStream.getBOM();
    String charsetName = bom == null ? defaultEncoding : bom.getCharsetName();
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(bOMInputStream), charsetName);
    //use reader
} finally {
    inputStream.close();
}
```

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/BOMInputStream.html

Comment: This code will only work with UTF-8 BOM detection and excluding. 
Check the implementation of bOMInputStream:
```
    /**
     * Constructs a new BOM InputStream that detects a
     * a {@link ByteOrderMark#UTF_8} and optionally includes it.
     * @param delegate the InputStream to delegate to
     * @param include true to include the UTF-8 BOM or
     * false to exclude it
     */
    public BOMInputStream(InputStream delegate, boolean include) {
        this(delegate, include, ByteOrderMark.UTF_8);
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's how I use the Apache BOMInputStream, it uses a try-with-resources block. The "false" argument tells the object to ignore the following BOMs (we use "BOM-less" text files for safety reasons, haha):

```
try( BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( 
    new InputStreamReader( new BOMInputStream( new FileInputStream(
       file), false, ByteOrderMark.UTF_8,
        ByteOrderMark.UTF_16BE, ByteOrderMark.UTF_16LE,
        ByteOrderMark.UTF_32BE, ByteOrderMark.UTF_32LE ) ) ) )
{
    // use br here

} catch( Exception e)

}
```

Comment: can never figure out how to post stuff on this site - always ends up AFU.

Comment: If you want a String then you can skip the `BufferedReader` and `InputStreamReader` and use `commons.io.IOUtils` instead: `String xml = IOUtils.toString(bomInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`

Answer (score 9):

Consider [UnicodeReader](https://github.com/google/gdata-java-client/blob/master/java/src/com/google/gdata/util/io/base/UnicodeReader.java) from Google which does all this work for you.

```
Charset utf8 = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;  // default if no BOM present
try (Reader r = new UnicodeReader(new FileInputStream(file), utf8.name())) {
    ....
}
```

Maven Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>1.47.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works well and with SuperCSV too. This earned me some browny points. :)

Comment: Excellent. Very easy solution, that worked great for OpenCSV

Answer (score 7):

Use [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi).

For example, let's take a look on my code (used for reading a text file with both latin and cyrillic characters) below:

```
String defaultEncoding = "UTF-16";
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("/temp/1.txt"));

BOMInputStream bomInputStream = new BOMInputStream(inputStream);

ByteOrderMark bom = bomInputStream.getBOM();
String charsetName = bom == null ? defaultEncoding : bom.getCharsetName();
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(bomInputStream), charsetName);
int data = reader.read();
while (data != -1) {

 char theChar = (char) data;
 data = reader.read();
 ari.add(Character.toString(theChar));
}
reader.close();
```

As a result we have an ArrayList named "ari" with all characters from file "1.txt" excepting BOM.

Answer (score 3):

If somebody wants to do it with the standard, this would be a way:

```
public static String cutBOM(String value) {
    // UTF-8 BOM is EF BB BF, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark
    String bom = String.format("%x", new BigInteger(1, value.substring(0,3).getBytes()));
    if (bom.equals("efbbbf"))
        // UTF-8
        return value.substring(3, value.length());
    else if (bom.substring(0, 2).equals("feff") || bom.substring(0, 2).equals("ffe"))
        // UTF-16BE or UTF16-LE
        return value.substring(2, value.length());
    else
        return value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/338836/awk-with-bom-is-there-any-cool-way-to-handle-unicode-bom-with-regexp/338930) that this is usually a problem with files on Windows.

One possible solution would be running the file through a tool like dos2unix first.

Comment: yes, `dos2unix` (which is part of cygwin) has options for adding (`--add-bom`) and removing (`--remove-bom`) bom.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I found to bypass BOM

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));    
while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    //case of, remove the BOM of UTF-8 BOM
                    currentLine = currentLine.replace("ï»¿","");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to read the String and don't want add more dependencies, you may simply use this code:

```java
    private static final byte[] BOM_UTF8 = new byte[] {(byte)0xEF, (byte) 0xBB,(byte)0xBF};

    //— Note: this code reads input as UTF-8 octets and strips optional BOM (Byte Order Mark) from the beginning.
    //  Unicode does not recommend placing BOM in front of UTF-8 byte sequence (as it simply does not add any value,
    //  since byte order in UTF-8 is always the same, no matter if we treat it in BE or LE order.
    private String readAsUtf8WithOptionalBom(InputStream input) throws IOException {
        var preamble = new byte[3];
        var read = input.read(preamble);
        if (read == -1) {
            return null;
        }
        if (read < 3) {
            return new String(preamble, 0, read, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }
        try (var output = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            if (!Arrays.equals(preamble, BOM_UTF8)) {
                output.write(preamble);
            }
            input.transferTo(output);
            return output.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }
    }
```