# Length of the first line in an UTF-8 file with BOM

Tags: clojure

Good afternoon. Suppose I have an utf-8 file with a single letter, say "f" (no \n and spaces) and I try to get a sequence of line lengths.

```
(with-open [rdr (reader "test.txt")] 
  (doall (map #(.length %) (line-seq rdr))))
```

And I get

```
=> (2)
```

Why? Is there any elegant way to get the right length of the first string?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. I used your code with UTF-8 file containing one- or two-byte characters, both with or without `\n` at the end. In all cases I got `(1)`. What's your Clojure version?

Comment: Just a random thought, what if you put a BOM in your test files ?

Comment: My Clojure version is 1.4. Yes, in reality that is BOM. How could I bypass the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem of BOM in Java is covered in [Reading UTF-8 - BOM marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897876/reading-utf-8-bom-marker). It seems that it can be abstracted away using [BOMInputStream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/BOMInputStream.html) from Apache's Commons or it has to be removed manually, i.e.

```
(defn debomify
  [^String line]
  (let [bom "\uFEFF"]
    (if (.startsWith line bom)
      (.substring line 1)
      line)))

(doall (map #(.length %) (.split (debomify (slurp "test.txt")) "\n")))
```

If you want to read a file lazily using `line-seq`, for instance because it's huge, you have to treat the first line using `debomify`. Remaining ones can be read normally. Hence:

```
(defn debommed-line-seq
  [^java.io.BufferedReader rdr]
  (when-let [line (.readLine rdr)]
    (cons (debomify line) (lazy-seq (line-seq rdr)))))
```

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps this is a solution.

Comment: Thanks for more detailed version.

Comment: Maybe the more optimal method is to do simply (debomify (slurp "test.txt")) and then split it.

Comment: @ОлегЛеонов, thanks, you're absolutely right. I've fixed the answer.

Comment: @MichielBorkent, ...a lazy approach would be welcome. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @MichielBorkent, that would indeed work, however there's no need to call `debomify` on each line of the read file. `debommed-line-seq` calls `debomify` only on the first one.

Comment: I'm afraid we've lost laziness: (is (instance? clojure.lang.LazySeq (debommed-line-seq (reader "test.txt")))) => false

Comment: @OlegLeonov, the first line is evaluated strictly and subsequent ones in a lazy seq. If you'd like the first one to be lazy as well wrap the call to `cons` in `lazy-seq`.

Comment: I appreciate your help. It seems to me that lazy-seq in expression (lazy-seq (line-seq rdr)) is unnecessary. I'd like to suggest final variant: (defn debommed-line-seq
  [^java.io.BufferedReader rdr]
  (when-let [line (.readLine rdr)]
    (lazy-seq (cons (debomify line) (line-seq rdr)))))

Comment: @OlegLeonov, in such case you'll get a lazy seq, whose tail will be a normal, strict cons, whose tail will be a lazy seq. This time the second element is non-lazy :). Also, take a look at the source of Clojure's [`line-seq`](http://www.clodoc.org/doc/clojure.core/line-seq). That's what I've based `debommed-line-seq` on. `line-seq` reads the first line strictly and remaining ones are read lazily.