# random characters in byte to string conversion java

Tags: java, encryption, type-conversion, arrays

I am converting byte [] into a string. Everytime that I convert the byte array to a string, it has a prefixed-type character before it every single time. I have tried different characters, uppercase, etc.. Still has the prefix.

When I write the byte code to system output, it still has the character.

```
System.out.write(theByteArray);

System.out.println(new String(theByteArray, "UTF-8"));
```

When I write the text to a file, it seems like the byte array printed flawlessly, but then I scan it and end up with the weird prefix symbol...

Text to be encrypted >

```
"aaaa"
```

Text when decrypted and converted to a string >

`"aaaa"`

The Character seems to disappear, here is an image of it.

[image: Image of characters]

I am wanting to compare the given string to another string, kind of like decrypting a password, and comparing it to a database. If one matches, then it gives access.

Code that is generating this byte code.

Keep in mind, the byte I am looking at is decData, and this is NOT my code.

```
byte[] encData;
        byte[] decData;
        File inFile = new File(fileName+ ".encrypted");

        //Generate the cipher using pass:
        Cipher cipher = FileEncryptor.makeCipher(pass, false);

        //Read in the file:
        FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(inFile);

        encData = new byte[(int)inFile.length()];
        inStream.read(encData);
        inStream.close();
        //Decrypt the file data:
        decData = cipher.doFinal(encData);
        //Figure out how much padding to remove

        int padCount = (int)decData[decData.length - 1];

        //Naive check, will fail if plaintext file actually contained
        //this at the end
        //For robust check, check that padCount bytes at the end have same value
        if( padCount >= 1 && padCount <= 8 ) {
            decData = Arrays.copyOfRange( decData , 0, decData.length - padCount);
        }
        FileOutputStream target = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName + ".decrypted.txt"));
        target.write(decData);
        target.close();
```

Comment: what's the prefix you're talking about?

Comment: I am not sure, it just disappears, let me get an image, sorry.

Comment: http://gyazo.com/d3187307c7a72ad13116a6f0e76762d5

Comment: Don't give links, use the image button on the editor.

Comment: What IDE (Eclipse, NetBeans, ...) are you using? Is this something that maybe your console prints? When you do simple System.out.println("aaaa") do you get this "prefix"?

Comment: What is the byte arrays value before you convert it to a string?

Comment: Before conversion: [B@72366ea0
IDE: BueJ

I have tested with an if statement: if(new String(byteArray, "UTF-8") == "Text")
It doesn't work though.

Comment: that is _not_ how you compare strings, you use `.equals()`.

Comment: show the code which is generating the byte[].

Comment: Using the .equals didn't seem to work either. I thought that was it :/

Comment: You need to walk through each of the characters of the string, and print out the (int) value of each character.

Comment: 65279
97
97
97
97
13
I get these numeric values when the text is aaaa
Where is 65279 and 13 coming from?

Comment: 65279 is the byte order mark and 13 is carriage return.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like encData contains [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) and I think Java, when reading in a stream with BOM, will just treat the BOM as an UTF-8 character, which caused the "prefix". You can try the solution suggested here: [Reading UTF-8 - BOM marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897876/reading-utf-8-bom-marker).

On the other hand, byte order mark is optional and not recommended for UTF-8 encoding. So two questions to ask is:

1. Is the original data encoded using utf-8?
2. If it is, it might be worth while to find out why did the BOM gets into the original data in the first place.