# reading group of numbers from file in order

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist, while-loop

I am trying to read numbers from file in order, but there is an issue with the first number in the file, reading example at the end of the question.

```
public static ArrayList<String> ArraylineLengths() {
            ArrayList<String> Lines = new ArrayList<String>();
            String file = "tra.srt";
            BufferedReader br = null;
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    
                String line;
                while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    line = line.trim();
                    if(isInteger(line)) {
                        int i = Integer.parseInt(line);
                        if(i > 0) {
                            Lines.add(line);
                            System.out.println(line);
                        }
                    }
                }
    
            } catch(IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if(br != null) {
                    try {
                        br.close();
                    } catch(IOException e) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                }
            }
            return (Lines);
    
        }
    
    
        public static boolean isInteger(String s) {
            try {
                Integer.parseInt(s);
            } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                return false;
            }
            // only got here if we didn't return false
            return true;
        }
    
    }
```

Input file:

```
1
00:01:09,069 --> 00:01:11,446
All right now.
Y'all fresh veggies.

2
00:01:11,571 --> 00:01:13,239
Y'all gonna be in a chopped salad.

3
00:01:13,573 --> 00:01:16,409
Very simple. I want you to take your knife.
```

What I should get is the number `1 2 3` etcetera, but instead I get:

> 2 3 4 5...etc.

This is because the first number at the top of the file if I used `substring(1,2)` it is going to work fine, but I can't because of an old issue in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22624203/method-are-reading-the-numbers-in-the-file-with-wrong-organization) .

After reading the file with HXD:

> EF BB BF 31 0D 0A 30 30 3A 30 30 3A 30 31 2C 36 30 30 20 2D 2D 3E 20
>
> 30 30 20 2D 2D 3E 20 30 30 3A 30 30 3A 30 34 2C

Comment: who down vote my question and why? don't just down vote and go

Comment: that's a SRT file. get a library that parses it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code, after having copy-pasted the input in a file, and it worked perfectly.

So, I think that you have an invisible character at the beginning of the file, and I think it may be a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

What you can do is use an hex editor to see the beginning of your file, and discover what is the problematic character.

Here is what I have when I do it on the input file I have:

```
$ hexdump -C /tmp/tra.srt | head
00000000  31 0a 30 30 3a 30 31 3a  30 39 2c 30 36 39 20 2d  |1.00:01:09,069 -|
```

As you can see, the file starts with `0x31`, which is the character *1*, and continues with `0x0a`, which is *\n*. If you have a BOM at the beginning of the file, it will start with `0xef 0xbb 0xbf`.

If you really have a BOM, you can have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897876/reading-utf-8-bom-marker) to see how to skip it, or you can just add the following code after trimming the line:

```
if (line.startsWith("\uFEFF"))
    line = line.substring(1);
```

Comment: your answer seem to be useful but and new i don't know why would some one to down vote my question anyway can you write a code to replace any /n char to null i think this going to fix the isuue

Comment: but as you write i don't have BOM right,so how i can replace char "\n"

Comment: @jackpeton The *\n* are not the problem, because the *\n* is a line feed, so if there is an *\n*, there is a new line. Have you tried to use an hexadecimal editor to see what is at the beginning of your file ?

Comment: i downloaded application called hxd

Comment: @jackpeton Under Linux, I just use `hexdump -C`, as you can see in the answer. If you are under Windows or Mac, you can search on google "hexadecimal editor", they should all give a good result.

Comment: @jackpeton Just saw your edit, you have a BOM at the beginning of the file ("EF BB BF").

Comment: @jackpeton I edited my answer, and added the code to remove the BOM.

Answer (score 0):

you can fix the issue by adding the line

```
line = line.replace("\uFEFF", "");
```