# Special character while using Files.readAllLines

Tags: java

i'm trying to use Files.readAllLines to read a file and editing it.

```
List<String> l = Files.readAllLines(manejador.getArchivo().toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

The file has a list of games and its players:

```
ID: Fm550.0
Federico Schmidt
Iván Petrini
Germán Gómez
Tomás  Perotti
ID: VO101000.0
Alex Morgan
```

So then, i want to check every position in the list to see if it is equals to some ID.

The problem is that when i use Files.readAllLines, i get this:

```
?ID: Fm550.0
Federico Schmidt
Iván Petrini
Germán Gómez
Tomás  Perotti
ID: VO101000.0
Alex Morgan
```

How can i get rid of that `?` at the beggining?

Comment: That character is probably in your file - how did you create the file?

Comment: Maybe it's a BOM. Look at your text file with a hex editor.

Comment: UTF-8 files *may* start with a BOM ([Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8)). You should open the file in a text editor (e.g. Notepad++) and save it without the BOM. From the wiki: *"The Unicode Standard **permits** the BOM in UTF-8, **but does not** require or **recommend its use**."*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading UTF-8 - BOM marker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897876/reading-utf-8-bom-marker)

Answer (score 0):

While your question is slightly different, i.e., not a  duplicate of [Reading UTF-8 - BOM marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897876/reading-utf-8-bom-marker) because it appears you may not have known the issue of BOM's in UTF-8, there is an answer for dealing with BOM in UTF-8 files in Java in the link above.