# Strings contain the same characters but are still different

Tags: java, android, string

I am trying to read a .txt file and use each sentence as a name for a team, and at the same time use that name to seek out another .txt file to get its content. All the .txt files are at the root of my assets folder. The first .txt file works fine, I use `assetmanager.open` and `readLine()` to obtain the string, but when using that string as a parameter to get the second .txt I get a `java.io.FileNotFoundException`. However, when calling that same .txt file with a hardcoded String, everything works fine. Upon further inspection I found out that the hardcoded string and the one used as a parameter return false after using the `equals()` function on it.

This is the method calling the `first.txt`

```
private void loadTeams() {
    try {
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(assetManager.open("matches.txt")));
        String name, bio, trainer;
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            name = r.readLine();
            bio = r.readLine();
            trainer = r.readLine();
            System.out.println(name+", "+bio+", "+trainer);
            teams[i] = new Team(name, bio, i, loadPlayers(name), trainer);
        }
        r.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

using "name" as a parameter for the following method:

```
private Player[] loadPlayers(String teamName){
    Player[] players = new Player[11];

    try {
        String path = "team_Netherlands.txt";     //works
        String path2 = "team_"+teamName+".txt";     //doesn't work?
        System.out.println("are "+path+" and " +path2 +" the same? "+path.equals(path2));

        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(assetManager.open(path2)));

        //perform operations on the obtained info
        r.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return players;
}
```

The first sentence in the file is "Netherlands" (without the quotes)
which I think should lead to `team_Netherlands.txt` for the *path2* variable.
using this will however crash the app. Using the *path* variable it works just fine. The println confirms that the strings are not equal. (See first sentence of the logcat)

logcat:

```
05-26 11:18:23.152 2960-2960/com.myname.testapp I/System.out: are team_Netherlands.txt and team_Netherlands.txt the same? false
05-26 11:18:23.152 2960-2960/com.myname.testapp W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: team_Netherlands.txt
05-26 11:18:23.152 2960-2960/com.myname.testapp W/System.err:     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
05-26 11:18:23.152 2960-2960/com.myname.testapp W/System.err:     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:354)
05-26 11:18:23.152 2960-2960/com.myname.testapp W/System.err:     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:328)
05-26 11:18:23.152 2960-2960/com.myname.testapp W/System.err:     at com.myname.testapp.Poule_Activity.load_Players(Poule_Activity.java:144)
05-26 11:18:23.152 2960-2960/com.myname.testapp W/System.err:     at com.myname.testapp.Poule_Activity.load_Teams(Poule_Activity.java:94)
05-26 11:18:23.152 2960-2960/com.myname.testapp W/System.err:     at com.myname.testapp.Poule_Activity.onCreate(Poule_Activity.java:53)
05-26 11:18:23.152 2960-2960/com.myname.testapp W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
05-26 11:18:23.152 2960-2960/com.myname.testapp W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
05-26 11:18:23.152 2960-2960/com.myname.testapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
05-26 11:18:23.152 2960-2960/com.myname.testapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
05-26 11:18:23.152 2960-2960/com.myname.testapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
05-26 11:18:23.152 2960-2960/com.myname.testapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
05-26 11:18:23.152 2960-2960/com.myname.testapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-26 11:18:23.152 2960-2960/com.myname.testapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
05-26 11:18:23.153 2960-2960/com.myname.testapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373)
05-26 11:18:23.153 2960-2960/com.myname.testapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-26 11:18:23.153 2960-2960/com.myname.testapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-26 11:18:23.153 2960-2960/com.myname.testapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
05-26 11:18:23.153 2960-2960/com.myname.testapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

Why aren't those strings equal and how to make them equal? (i.e., make the non-hardcoded string equal to the hardcoded one)

Comment: check both String lengths

Comment: thank you for your quick response :)
I think you are on to something: path  length: 20, path2 length: 16, do you know what could have caused this?

Comment: try `path.trim().equals(path2.trim())`

Comment: @Amit.rk3, still returns false :(

Comment: or `"team_"+team_Name.trim()+".txt"`, I guess this should have been my first comment :)

Comment: that one also returns false, but path is the hardcoded one and that one has length 20, whilst path2 has only 16

Comment: I tried its coming both strings are equal. Check the string you are passing whether any special character is added

Comment: Can u please put the chunk of code where you are generating team_Name.

Comment: @PreethiRao the team_name is a simple textfile that I have written in notepad++, the .txt files function as a script

Comment: After a lot of saving and resaving I managed to get rid of the BOM in the encoding. not sure if I should give credits to Jordi Castilla or laalto(can't tag), but thank you everyone for helping me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `team_name` you read from file contains [UTF-8 byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) octets in front

```
ef bb bf
```

and they are not visible as such in log output.

Either save the files without BOM, or [remove the BOM in your code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897876/reading-utf-8-bom-marker)

Comment: how you check it taking the string from here? I can see equals and hashCode does not match, but cannot find this hidden chars...

Comment: @JordiCastilla copy-pasted to hexdump

Comment: ... though now it seems the BOM was lost in @ErikKralj's edit. Anyway, it's there in the original version.

Answer (score 7):

If I execute this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    load_Players("Netherlands");
}

private static void load_Players(String team_Name) {
    String path = "team_Netherlands.txt"; // works
    String path2 = "team_" + team_Name + ".txt"; // doesn't work?
    System.out.println("are " + path + " and " + path2 + " the same? " + path.equals(path2));
}
```

All works as expected, so... what's wrong?

---

As you can see in your log, first Netherlands is not blue, what means parser has found something different.

[image]

**Suspicious uh?**

---

**CHECKS:**

When I paste this part of code into my eclipse:

```
team_Netherlands.txt and team_Netherlands.txt
```

I get this error when saving:

[image]

If I choose option select first character it selects:

```
System.out.println("team_Netherlands.txt".equals("team_Netherlands.txt"));
                                                       ↑ this one!!!
```

So you're passing wrong encoding as you can check with this snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String rightString = "_Netherlands.txt";
    String wrongString = "_Netherlands.txt";

    System.out.println("WRONG HASH");
    System.out.println(rightString.hashCode());
    System.out.println("\nRIGHT HASH");
    System.out.println(wrongString.hashCode());

    System.out.println("\nRIGHT");
    printChars(rightString);

    System.out.println("\n\nWRONG");
    printChars(wrongString);

}

private static void printChars(String s) {
    for (Character c : s.toCharArray()) {
        System.out.print((int) c + " ");
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
WRONG HASH
1109617587

RIGHT HASH
-428164238

RIGHT
95 78 101 116 104 101 114 108 97 110 100 115 46 116 120 116 

WRONG
95 65279 78 101 116 104 101 114 108 97 110 100 115 46 116 120 116 
// ↑ here!!
```

---

**SOLUTION's: ([source](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-handle-utf8-file-with-bom.html))**

- Use `BOMInputStream` from Apache IO Commons
- Handle manually (fast easy way):

  ```
  private static String clean(String s) throws Exception {
      InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes());
      try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) {
          // BOM marker will only appear on the very beginning
          br.mark(4);
          if ('\ufeff' != br.read())
              br.reset(); // not the BOM marker

          return br.readLine();
      }
  }
  ```

**TEST IT!:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String rightString = "Netherlands.txt";
    String wrongString = "Netherlands.txt";

    System.out.println("\nCOMPARE");
    System.out.println(rightString.equals(wrongString));
    System.out.println("\nCLEAN COMPARE");
    System.out.println(clean(rightString).equals(clean(wrongString)));

    System.out.println("\nRIGHT");
    printChars(clean(rightString));

    System.out.println("\n\nWRONG");
    printChars(clean(wrongString));
}

private static String clean(String s) throws Exception {
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes());
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) {
        // BOM marker will only appear on the very beginning
        br.mark(4);
        if ('\ufeff' != br.read())
            br.reset(); // not the BOM marker

        return br.readLine();
    }
}

private static void printChars(String s) {
    for (Character c : s.toCharArray()) {
        System.out.print((int) c + " ");
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
COMPARE
false

CLEAN COMPARE
true

RIGHT
78 101 116 104 101 114 108 97 110 100 115 46 116 120 116 

WRONG
78 101 116 104 101 114 108 97 110 100 115 46 116 120 116
```

Comment: ooh i see, I think that makes sense, I'll change the encoding and let you know what comes out of it :)

Comment: unfortunately changing everything to UTF-8 has not helped, what would be the correct encoding needed?

Comment: please kindly check my update.

Comment: oh sorry I had not seen that, thank you for the update!

Comment: you're welcome. I also posted a last update with a working code and solution, you found an interesting bug and I want to learn more about it... but **I agree accepted answer is @laalto one, I was guided by him and links provided. :)**

Answer (score 1):

it's must be have some Invisible characters.

could you show us `path.getBytes()` and `path2.getBytes()`,output array datas.

Comment: turned out to be the encoding that caused the unequal strings, which would have resulted from that as well. Sorry for the late response, I was working through all the possible solution and had not seen your post yet. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
    String s1="abc    def";
    String s2="abc def";
    s1=s1.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
    System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
```

Apparently, the String from the text files seems good to go but you can still have options to do something like above to precise the equals!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer to your problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java). The strings you are comparing are different objects that is why you get false. You are not actually comparing the value that those strings contain.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the encoding.
The names you are reading from the text file are UTF encoded.

What you can try and do is

```
String path3 = new String(path, "UTF-8");
String path4 = new String(path2, "UTF-8");
```

Do a string compare on path3 and path4 now and check.

Comment: android studio says it cannot resolve the constructor with two strings, and removing the quotes at UTF-8 does not work either