# Two Equal Strings do not pass assertion

Tags: java, xml, string, equals, assert

I'm trying to compare a String to a file-content, and want to assert wheather they are equal or not.

Like:

```
13CB0000000000X15.xml (input)
13CB0000000000X15.xml (expected (content of file))
```

My Assert:

```
assertTrue("Tatsaechliches Ergebnis weicht von '" 
+ expectedResultFileName + "' ab!", result.equals(expected));
```

This assertion somehow fails, because it says its **not** equal?!

My file is UTF-8 w/o BOM. There is no LF/ CRLF or else. I even tried to trim it with:

```
    String expected = readFile(testDataBasePath + 
    File.separator + expectedResultFileName, encoding);
    expected = expected.trim();

    String result   = document.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();             
    result = result.trim();
```

What am I missing?

Comment: So you never checked the bytes contained in these String and which bytes are missing/surplus?

Comment: Hint: when equals() tells you that your strings aren't equal; then they arent. Try to compare them character wise for example.

Comment: Thanks @GhostCat, got it solved with ur methode. For the record:

`char[] first  = w1.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
char[] second = w2.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

int minLength = Math.min(first.length, second.length);

for(int i = 0; i < minLength; i++)
{
        if (first[i] != second[i])
        {
            return false;    
        }
}
return true;`

Comment: @HendrikHeim Better tell us which character were different. :)

Comment: @lexicore How is that important? This question is a "why doesn't this code work" question without a proper mcve and even if this will be fixed, what value does this have for future readers? I would vote to delete, if I could.

Comment: @Tom I agree that absent MCVE is a close reason. I disagree that the question can't be helpful for future readers. The core of the question is "how can equally-looking strings be not equal" and it's not bad to know possible reasons for this. For the same reason I'm interested in the particular problem which was the case here.

Comment: @lexicore *"how can equally-looking strings be not equal"* There are other questions for this already. I'm currently looking for a good dupe to close vote this one here.

Comment: Arr, way too many questions about general String comparison, but anyway this is a quite useful dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37457545/strings-contain-the-same-characters-but-are-still-different. Although it asks about the BOM and OP said it isn't a problem in his case, the answers contain general ways to analyze two Strings, like checking the characters or bytes.

Comment: @HendrikHeim Your solution in the comment would be wrong for `w1 = "foo"; and w2 = "foobar"`. Either provide an example which demonstrate that it's failing like you said or delete/close your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your string are not equal, period. They might *look* equal when you print them out but there's a lot of tricks like different types of space characters, all looking the same. Or as simple as mixing lowecase `l` and uppercase `I` which are almost indistinguishable with some fonts.

One hint: consider using `assertEquals(..., a, b)` instead of `assertTrue(..., a.equals(b))`. The former may give you a better message in some IDEs, showing exactly where strings differ.