# Apache Commons CSV parser: Not able to read the values

Tags: java-8, apache-commons-csv

I am using apache commons CSV parser to convert the CSV to a map. In the map I couldnt able to read some values through intellij debuger. if I manually type map.get("key") the value is null. However, if I copy paste the key from the map, I am getting data. Couldnt understand what is going wrong. Any pointers would help. Thanks

Here is my CSV parser code:

```
 private CSVParser parseCSV(InputStream inputStream) {
        System.out.println("What is the encoding "+ new InputStreamReader(inputStream).getEncoding());
        try {
            return new CSVParser(new InputStreamReader(inputStream), CSVFormat.DEFAULT
                    .withFirstRecordAsHeader()
                    .withIgnoreHeaderCase()
                    .withSkipHeaderRecord()
                    .withTrim());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IPRSException(e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a weird character in the strings (Reference: [Reading UTF-8 - BOM marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897876/reading-utf-8-bom-marker)). The below syntax help to resolve the issue

```
header = header("\uFEFF", "");
```

Comment: What "header()" method is this?

Comment: its one of the key in the map

Comment: The correct syntax here is ```header = header.replaceAll("\uFEFF", "");```

Answer (score 2):

in java use UnicodeReader:

```
String path = "demo.csv";
CSVFormat.Builder builder = CSVFormat.RFC4180.builder();
CSVFormat format = builder.setQuote(null).setHeader().build();

InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
CSVParser parser = new CSVParser(new BufferedReader(new UnicodeReader(in)), format);
```

Comment: Probably you meant [UnicodeReader](https://github.com/google/gdata-java-client/blob/master/java/src/com/google/gdata/util/io/base/UnicodeReader.java) from Google