# Strange character in the begining xml file

Tags: java, xml, character-encoding

I´m trying to parse one xml but it shows a error, if I put a `system.out.println` to the `String` i see it.

before

```
ï»¿<?xml version="1.0"
```

after

```
?<?xml version="1.0"
```

I´m changing the charset to `UTF-8` but didn´t works, so, what should I do?

Comment: Is it a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)?

Comment: In my search in google, it seens to be, but the whole `String` of my code is a invoice, I want to parse, but `Sax` makes a `exception`

Comment: More specifically, it's a BOM that has been decoded using the wrong encoding. If the file is read as UTF-8, then the BOM is interpreted as a single zero-width space character, or removed entirely by the software reading the file. If you read the file using an 8-bit encoding, you get three unusal characters as in the first example.

Comment: So what should I do? Looking in notepead++ it shows UTF-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For someone who wants to parse a xml and is having some problem with parse because of `BOM` this code above worked to me.

You can use API from apache [BomInpustStream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/BOMInputStream.html), it does the job for you, I had this problem, and you can trust, using this API will be much easier. A tip for you when parse a `XML`, you will need to get this as a array of `bytes`, check with the API suggested, and later parse to `String` in the `charset UTF-8`, in this way you will not lost the accents..

Piece of code to transform a source in inputStream

```
String source = FileUtil.takeOffBOM(IOUtils.toInputStream(attachment.getValue()));
```

Method to take off the BOM

```
public static String takeOffBOM(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    BOMInputStream bomInputStream = new BOMInputStream(inputStream);
    return IOUtils.toString(bomInputStream, "UTF-8");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a UTF-8 string (which is why Notepad++ is recognizing it as such), but UTF-8 doesn't *require* a BOM. Some programs produce it; some don't. This leads to occasional confusion when reading files - some readers (like the one you're using in your Java code) don't recognize and ignore it. I'd recommend something like the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736999/how-to-remove-bom-from-an-xml-file-in-java) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835430/byte-order-mark-screws-up-file-reading-in-java) for removing it. Make sure you implement a check to determine if the first 3 bytes actually *are* a BOM before removing them from *all* incoming strings.

Comment: I read and I think that i need to verify if the begin of the file has the BOM and if have, remove it.

Comment: If you're parsing the XML with an XML library, it should tolerate the BOM (it's in the rules of XML that you have to accept a BOM in UTF-8). It's not impossible that somewhere along the line of producing the file you actually ended up with two BOMs.

Comment: The "rules of XML" have only said this since the 3rd edition, and some XML parsers are older than that.

Comment: @user2283439 Yep; that's what I suggested. Your XML parser might not be doing this for you, so this should be your first step (unless you're somehow reading the file in Java as ASCII/Latin-1/CP-1252 text before you feed it to your parser; that would cause this problem too).

Answer (score 1):

A lot of utilities produce such initial odd character.

You may use java code to skip any character before the first "<". If your xml file is yours, you can fix it for good with, for example:

```
vi # no filename here, we need first to get in binary mode.
:set binary
:e filename.containing.your.xml
dt<:w
:q!
```