# Efficiently removing UTF Byte order Mark

Tags: java, xml, utf-8, jaxb, byte-order-mark

I am looking for an efficient solution to the following problem:

[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138696/org-xml-sax-saxparseexception-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog)

The problem is skipping (or removing) the first 3 bom bytes (if present) before unmarshalling the file (using jaxb).

I can get it to work by checking the first three bytes and then writing everything after that to a new file and using the new file, however this seems horribly inefficient.

I have tried moving the file pointer over 3 bytes if the BOM is present (and verified the pointer position ofc.) , however when I pass the inputstream to jaxb it still throws the same exception; my gut instinct being that the file pointer is being reset.

Does anyone have any ideas for this?

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1835430/260633 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/5353783/260633

Answer (score 5):

Use a `InputStream` decoractor that strips the BOM such as [`BOMInputStream`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/BOMInputStream.html) from Apache Commons IO.