# Remove non-ASCII non-printable characters from a String

Tags: java, non-ascii-characters

I get user input including non-ASCII characters and non-printable characters, such as

```
\xc2d
\xa0
\xe7
\xc3\ufffdd
\xc3\ufffdd
\xc2\xa0
\xc3\xa7
\xa0\xa0
```

for example:

```
email : abc@gmail.com\xa0\xa0
street : 123 Main St.\xc2\xa0
```

desired output:

```
  email : abc@gmail.com
  street : 123 Main St.
```

What is the best way to removing them using Java?
I tried the following, but doesn't seem to work

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String s = "abc@gmail\\xe9.com";
        String email = "abc@gmail.com\\xa0\\xa0";

        System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\P{Print}", ""));
        System.out.println(email.replaceAll("\\P{Print}", ""));
    }
```

Output

```
abc@gmail\xe9.com
abc@gmail.com\xa0\xa0
```

Comment: why do you want to remove them?

Comment: @jtahlborn, Mongo fails to serialize these values

Comment: @daydreamer [citation needed] [\xc2d](http://www.codetable.net/hex/c2d) is a valid Unicode character. If MongoDB uses UTF-8 is should be able to serialize them. Perhaps you have an XY Problem here? How are you serializing your text?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Your requirements are not clear. All characters in a Java `String` are Unicode characters, so if you remove them, you'll be left with an empty string. I assume what you mean is that you want to remove any non-ASCII, non-printable characters.

```
String clean = str.replaceAll("\\P{Print}", "");
```

Here, `\p{Print}` [represents a POSIX character class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) for printable ASCII characters, while `\P{Print}` is the complement of that class. With this expression, all characters that are *not* printable ASCII are replaced with the empty string. (The extra backslash is because `\` starts an escape sequence in string literals.)

---

Apparently, all the input characters are actually ASCII characters that represent a printable encoding of non-printable or non-ASCII characters. Mongo shouldn't have any trouble with these strings, because they contain only plain printable ASCII characters.

This all sounds a little fishy to me. What I believe is happening is that the data really do contain non-printable and non-ASCII characters, and another component (like a logging framework) is replacing these with a printable representation. In your simple tests, you are failing to translate the printable representation back to the original string, so you mistakenly believe the first regular expression is not working.

That's my guess, but if I've misread the situation and you really do need to strip out literal `\xHH` escapes, you can do it with the following regular expression.

```
String clean = str.replaceAll("\\\\x\\p{XDigit}{2}", "");
```

---

The API documentation for the [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class does a good job of listing all of the syntax supported by Java's regex library. For more elaboration on what all of the syntax means, I have found the [Regular-Expressions.info site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) very helpful.

Comment: this doesn't work. may be I am doing something incorrect, but not working

Comment: @daydreamer Can you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that shows what is not working?

Comment: public static void main(String args[]) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String s = "abc@gmail\\xe9.com";
        String email = "abc@gmail.com\\xa0\\xa0";

        System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\P{Print}", ""));
        System.out.println(email.replaceAll("\\P{Print}", ""));
    }
out put - 
abc@gmail\xe9.com
abc@gmail.com\xa0\xa0

Comment: @daydreamer `\\x` doesn't mean anything special in Java source code. \\ in a `String` or `char` literal is an escape sequence that is replaced with \. If you want a Unicode escape, use `\uXXXX`, where XXXX is the Unicode point, in hexadecimal.

Comment: @daydreamer E.g. `String s = "abc@gmail\u00e9.com";`

Comment: ah I see, but the input I get is what I shared with you, does it mean it is not possible to strip it away?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12711/discussion-between-daydreamer-and-erickson)

Comment: No, you just need a different regular expression; your input is, apparently, all ASCII. Please see the update to my answer.

Comment: that seems to work, where I can learn more about creating such patterns like you created? please advice and thank you very much for your help, I appreciate it

Comment: @daydreamer I added a couple of links to great learning resources to the end of my answer.

Comment: how to remove this one �

Comment: "All characters in a Java String are Unicode characters, so if you remove them, you'll be left with an empty string." xD

Answer (score 16):

With [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [`CharMatcher`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html), you can remove any [non-printable](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html#invisible()) characters and then retain all ASCII characters (dropping any accents) like this:

```
String printable = CharMatcher.INVISIBLE.removeFrom(input);
String clean = CharMatcher.ASCII.retainFrom(printable);
```

Not sure if that's what you really want, but it removes anything expressed as escape sequences in your question's sample data.

Comment: note, INVISIBLE removed whitespace which I find odd since it is indeed "printable"

Answer (score 16):

I know it's maybe late but for future reference:

```
String clean = str.replaceAll("\\P{Print}", "");
```

Removes all non printable characters, but that includes `\n` (line feed), `\t`(tab) and `\r`(carriage return), and sometimes you want to keep those characters.

For that problem use inverted logic:

```
String clean = str.replaceAll("[^\\n\\r\\t\\p{Print}]", "");
```

Comment: Upvoted for it's particular usefulness in mongo-land, to keep the shell from spewing ridiculous amounts of encoded non-ascii stuff (mongo really really prefers utf-8 if you want things to be easy)

Comment: Got error: illegal escape character
         String clean = str.replaceAll("[^\n\r\t\p{Print}]", ""); . \p should be \P

Comment: Really helped me a lot  Thanks @Ivan

Answer (score 4):

You can try this code:

```
public String cleanInvalidCharacters(String in) {
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    char current;
    if (in == null || ("".equals(in))) {
        return "";
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++) {
        current = in.charAt(i);
        if ((current == 0x9)
                || (current == 0xA)
                || (current == 0xD)
                || ((current >= 0x20) && (current <= 0xD7FF))
                || ((current >= 0xE000) && (current <= 0xFFFD))
                || ((current >= 0x10000) && (current <= 0x10FFFF))) {
            out.append(current);
        }

    }
    return out.toString().replaceAll("\\s", " ");
}
```

It works for me to remove invalid characters from `String`.

Comment: That's a lot of magic numbers. How about extracting these clauses (especially the ranges) into aptly named local variables?

Answer (score 2):

You can use java.text.normalizer

Answer (score 0):

Input => "**This** \u7279**text** \u7279**is what I need**"
Output => "**This text is what I need**"

If you are trying to remove Unicode characters from a string like above this code will work

```
Pattern unicodeCharsPattern = Pattern.compile("\\\\u(\\p{XDigit}{4})");
Matcher unicodeMatcher = unicodeChars.matcher(data);
String cleanData = null;
if (unicodeMatcher.find()) {
    cleanData = unicodeMatcher.replaceAll("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple function worked better for me:

```
function remove_non_ascii(str) {
  
    if ((str===null) || (str===''))
         return false;
   else
     str = str.toString();
    
    return str.replace(/[^\x20-\x7E]/g, '');
}
```