# Java cleaning up String values to remove unwanted characters

Tags: java

I have a XML file which contains values having unwanted characters like

```
\xc2d
d\xa0
\xe7
\xc3\ufffdd
\xc3\ufffdd
\xc2\xa0
\xc3\xa7
\xa0\xa0
'619d813\xa03697'
\xe9.com
```

input examples could be

```
name : John Hinners\xc2d
email: abc@gmail\xe9.com
and others ....
```

desired output should be

```
name : John Hinners
email: abc@gmail.com
and others ....
```

I come from python background where this task can be done easily as

```
def remove_non_ascii(s):
    return ''.join(i for i in s if ord(i)<128)
```

Is there some similar way to perform the same task in Java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java removing unicode characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020893/java-removing-unicode-characters)

Answer (score 2):

As I said here:

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31424164/2630033)

Use regex

```
String clean = str.replaceAll("\\P{Print}", "");
```

Removes all non printable characters. 
But that also includes \n (line feed), \t(tab) and \r(carriage return), and if you want to keep those characters use:

```
String clean = str.replaceAll("[^\\n\\r\\t\\p{Print}]", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

In java it will not be as pretty.

You can use a regexp but if you don't have a simple definition of your characters the best is probably to do this :

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
           if (((int)s.charAt(i))<128) sb.append(s.charAt(i));
        }
```

Comment: Note that you don't have to cast between char and int in java; they are interchangeable.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I always feel the intent is more clear with the casting but it may be stupid (or due to the fact that I don't change habits when changing language).

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "WantedCharactersunwantedCharacters";
```

If I want the remaining String to be "WantedCharacters", I simply write:

```
s = s.replaceAll("unwantedCharacters", "");
```

[EDIT]:
You could, of course, also write

```
private static String removeNonAscii(String s){
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); ++i){
        if(s.charAt(i) < 128){
            sb.append(s.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

if that's a satisfying solution

Comment: i had big problems with replaceAll ... its not working like expected ... "replaceAll("\\");" and something like that....