# Java - Regex Replace All will not replace matched text

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

Trying to remove a lot of unicodes from a string but having issues with regex in java.

**Example text:**

> \u2605 StatTrak\u2122 Shadow Daggers

**Example Desired Result:**

> StatTrak Shadow Daggers

The current regex code I have that will not work:

```
list.replaceAll("\\\\u[0-9]+","");
```

The code will execute but the text will not be replaced. From looking at other solutions people seem to use only two "\\" but anything less than 4 throws me the typical error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal Unicode escape sequence near index 2
>   \u[0-9]+

I've tried the current regex solution in online test environments like [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) and [FreeFormatter](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output) and both give the correct result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020893/java-removing-unicode-characters

Comment: [Works fine for me.](https://ideone.com/J5Ni0m) Is that your actual text, or are those unicode literals?

Comment: Are you trying to replace from a string? or a list of strings? Wondering because your variable name is called `list`

Comment: I'm an idiot, I assumed "list.replaceAll(stuff,stuff)" would change the String without assignment.

Fixed it by just adding list = list.replaceAll(stuff,stuff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot. I was calling the replaceAll on the string but not assigning it as I thought it altered the string anyway.

What I had previously:

```
list.replaceAll("\\\\u[0-9]+","");
```

What I needed:

```
list = list.replaceAll("\\\\u[0-9]+","");
```

Result works fine now, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you would like to replace a "special string" to empty String. As I see, `\u2605` and `\u2122` are `POSIX` character class. That's why we can try to replace these printable characters to "". Then, the result is the same as your expectation.

Sample would be:

```
list = list.replaceAll("\\P{Print}", "");
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Can you also explain your approach? Is more helpful than a *code only* answer in general.

Comment: Assuming that he/she would like to replace a "special string" to empty String. As I see, \u2605 and \u2122 are POSIX character class. That's why I try to replace these printable characters to "". Then, the result is  the same his/her expectation. Hope it is clear for you guys.

Comment: Better now, thanks. Can you edit your answer and include that additional information directly in it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks Zabuza for the comments. Will edit it right away.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, something like your `\u2605` is not a literal sequence of six characters, it represents a single unicode character — therefore your pattern `"\\\\u[0-9]{4}"` will not match it.

Your pattern describes a literal character `\` followed by the character `u` followed by exactly four numeric characters `0` through `9` but what is in your string is the *single character* from the unicode code point 2605, the "Black Star" character.

This is just as other escape sequences: in the string `"some\tmore"` there is no character `\` and there is no character `t` ... there is only the single character 0x09, a *tab character* — because it is an escape sequence known to Java (and other languages) it gets replaced by the character that it *represents* and the literal `\` `t` are no longer characters in the string.

Kenny Tai Huynh's answer, replacing non-printables, may be the easiest way to go, depending on what sorts of things you want removed, or you could list the characters you want (if that is a very limited set) and remove the complement of those, such as `mystring.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");`

Comment: I was making a stupid mistake forgetting to assign the change variable. The pattern does work fine, but your solution is also helpful.