# remove unicode characters in given example and print relevant data

Tags: java, unicode, ascii, non-ascii-characters

i want to remove Unicode characters like ÇÈý.. and print CEy

```
    String str = "õvÉnkÄtèsh\u7279";
    System.out.println(str);
    str = str.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
    System.out.println("After removing non ASCII chars:");
    System.out.println(str);
```

input: õvÉnkÄtèsh特

output:vnktsh

but i want like this

**input** : VÈnkät@

**output**: VEnkat

**here is the code**

```
    String name="VÈnkät@";
    String input = StringUtils.stripAccents(name);
    input=input.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
    System.out.println("remove special characters after="+input);
```

**input** : VÈnkät@

**output**: VEnkat

please add "commons-lang3-3.0.jar"

Comment: Already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3322174/1484679

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020893/java-removing-unicode-characters

Comment: Please remove your answer from the question and post it as an answer. Ideally, after some time, you would accept the best sufficient answer (possibly yours).

Comment: All the characters are Unicode characters.