# Most efficient way to check if a file is empty in Java on Windows

Tags: java, file, logging, file-io, filesystems

I am trying to check if a log file is empty (meaning no errors) or not, in Java, on Windows. I have tried using 2 methods so far.

**Method 1 (Failure)**

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(sLogFilename));  
int iByteCount = fis.read();  
if (iByteCount == -1)  
    System.out.println("NO ERRORS!");
else
    System.out.println("SOME ERRORS!");
```

**Method 2 (Failure)**

```
File logFile = new File(sLogFilename);
if(logFile.length() == 0)
    System.out.println("NO ERRORS!");
else
    System.out.println("SOME ERRORS!");
```

Now both these methods fail at times when the log file is empty (has no content), yet the file size is not zero (2 bytes).

What is the most efficient *and* accurate method to check if the file is empty? I asked for efficiency, as I have to keep checking the file size thousands of times, in a loop.

*Note:* The file size would hover around a few to 10 KB only!

**Method 3 (Failure)**

Following @Cygnusx1's suggestion, I had tried using a `FileReader` too, without success. Here's the snippet, if anyone's interested.

```
Reader reader = new FileReader(sLogFilename);
int readSize = reader.read();
if (readSize == -1)
    System.out.println("NO ERRORS!");
else
    System.out.println("SOME ERRORS!");
```

Comment: I don`t understand how the file can be empty and still have a size of 2 bytes?  I have wrote the exact same code as you and with an empty file, i get the expected result NO ERRORS in your case.

Comment: ok forget my comment, just read about BOM and unicode.

Comment: Unicode encoding often uses a BOM field as an identifier, which takes up 255 bytes. My guess is, your empty file is ANSI encoded. Try with Unicode encoding.

Comment: yeah i saw, question: do you have control on the creation of this log file?  Could you change it's encoding to UTF-8?  it would solve your problem.

Comment: I've considered that. But in my specific case, sadly, no.

Comment: @GPX - A BOM doesn't take up to 255 bytes.  It takes just 3 bytes in UTF-8 or 2 bytes in UTF-16.  (Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Check if the first line of file is empty:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path_to_some_file"));     
if (br.readLine() == null) {
    System.out.println("No errors, and file empty");
}
```

Comment: Well I guess I'll use this method, as this works. Can you say this is the most efficient method?

Comment: Update: This method doesn't work either. When I use `readLine()`, it returns these junk characters - `ÿþ`. Now I'm confused.

Comment: This method *does* work if the input file is ANSI-encoded. Marking this as the answer.

Comment: Am I missing something or is there no file.readLine() method?

Comment: @w25r java.io.File.readLine() doesn't exist, Victor is referring to an example use of a BufferedReader.readLine(). I've updated the answer so that it isn't confusing anymore.

Comment: when I use this, the main class throws an error.
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:134)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:72)

Comment: This method doesn't work if the file encoding is ANSI, for example there are 10 blank-lines and than comes a character, the first line will be null yes, but the others maybe not.

Comment: This method is not working for CSV. I tried with an empty CSV file. with debugger if i wait some time it will return null wuthout debugger always return object

Answer (score 24):

Why not just use:

```
File file = new File("test.txt");

if (file.length() == 0) {
    // File empty
} else {
    // Not empty
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work with Unicode files. Check **Method 2** in my original post.

Comment: It also returns long the file.length() method

Comment: @GPX Sorry for being tardy to class. When you say a unicode file can be empty but have bytes, are you referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516343/why-empty-text-file-contains-3-bytes)?

Answer (score 3):

This is an improvement of Saik0's answer based on Anwar Shaikh's comment that too big files (above available memory) will throw an exception:

Using Apache Commons FileUtils

```
private void printEmptyFileName(final File file) throws IOException {
    /*Arbitrary big-ish number that definitely is not an empty file*/
    int limit = 4096;
    if(file.length < limit && FileUtils.readFileToString(file).trim().isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("File is empty: " + file.getName());
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can choose try the FileReader approach but it may not be time to give up just yet.
If is the BOM field destroying for you try this solution posted here at stackoverflow.

[Byte order mark screws up file reading in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835430/byte-order-mark-screws-up-file-reading-in-java/1835529#1835529)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

> Now both these methods fail at times when the log file is empty (has no content), yet the file size is not zero (2 bytes).

Actually, I think you will find that the file is NOT empty.  Rather I think that you will find that those two characters are a CR and a NL; i.e. the file consists of one line that is empty.  A truly empty file does in fact have a file size of zero.

If you want to test if a file is either empty or has a single empty line then a simple, relatively efficient way is:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(FileReader(fileName))) {
    String line = br.readLine();
    if (line == null || 
        (line.length() == 0 && br.readLine() == null)) {
        System.out.println("NO ERRORS!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("SOME ERRORS!");
    }
}
```

Can we do this more efficiently?  Possibly.  It depends on how often you have to deal with the three different cases:

- a completely empty file
- a file consisting of a single empty line
- a file with a non-empty line, or multiple lines.

You can probably do better by using `Files.length()` and / or reading just the first two bytes.  However, the problems include:

- If you both test the file size AND read the first few bytes then you are making 2 syscalls.
- The actual line termination sequence could be CR, NL or CR NL, depending on the platform.  (I know you say this is for Windows, but what happens if you need to port your application?  Or if someone sends you a non-Windows file?)
- It would be nice to avoid setting up stream / reader stack, but the file's character encoding *could* map CR and NL to something other than the bytes `0x0d` and `0x0a`.  (For example ... UTF-16)
- Then there's the annoying habit of some Windows utilities have putting [byte order markers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) into UTF-8 encoded files.  (This would even mess up the simple version above!)  A BOM is the Unicode code point U+FEFF which will render as 3 bytes in UTF-8 and 2 bytes in UTF-16 and 4 bytes in UTF-32.

All of this means that the most efficient possible solution is going to be rather complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Try `FileReader`, this reader is meant to read stream of character, while `FileInputStream` is meant to read raw data.

From the Javadoc:

> FileReader is meant for reading streams of characters. For reading
>   streams of raw bytes, consider using a FileInputStream.

Since you wanna read a log file, `FileReader` is the class to use IMO.

Comment: Yeah, i did a test with both methods and they work the same way.  In the end, my suggestion is still valid, but it does not solve the unicode BOM problem.  Look at Farmor answer and the link to another answer about this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is (using `Apache Commons` `FileUtils`) -

```cs
private void printEmptyFileName(final File file) throws IOException {
    if (FileUtils.readFileToString(file).trim().isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("File is empty: " + file.getName());
    }        
}
```

Comment: The method readFileToString(..) method will give exception "Java heap space error" if file is huge and insufficient memory available.

Answer (score 1):

```
String line = br.readLine();
String[] splitted = line.split("anySplitCharacter");
if(splitted.length == 0)
    //file is empty
else
    //file is not empty
```

I had the same problem with my text file. Although it was empty, the value being returned by the readLine method was not null. Therefore, I tried to assign its value to the String array which I was using to access the splitted attributes of my data. It did work for me. Try this out and tell me if it works for u as well.

Comment: Why not check if `line.isEmpty()`?

Comment: Its because br.readLine will return a non-null value because when a file is created, although it looks empty, it isn't actually empty. I don't know for sure which characters are already inside it but the file is not empty even though it looks as if it is.

Comment: What's your point? You think `isEmpty()` will return true if it *looks* empty?

Comment: No, I did not mean that isEmpty() will return true if it looks empty. We all know that a String is an array of characters and we also know that isEmpty() returns true if the length of the String is zero, but these hidden junk characters that I was talking about are not visible in the file if we open it but they are there and add upto the length of the String thus making isEmpty() an inappropriate method to use here.

Comment: Why would splitting operate differently?

Answer (score 1):

I combined the two best solutions to cover all the possibilities:

```java
File file = new File(fileName);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));     
if (br.readLine() == null && file.length() == 0)
{
    System.out.println("No errors, and file empty");
}                
else
{
    System.out.println("File contains something");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stolen from http://www.coderanch.com/t/279224/Streams/java/Checking-empty-file

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("file_name"));  
int b = fis.read();  
if (b == -1)  
{  
  System.out.println("!!File " + file_name + " emty!!");  
}
```

Updated: My first answer was premature and contained a bug.

Comment: Shouldn't I consider Rob's thoughts on the same page?

Comment: Yes sorry my first post was premature :(

Answer (score 0):

The idea of your first snippet is right. You probably meant to check `iByteCount == -1`: whether the file *has* at least one byte:

```
if (iByteCount == -1)  
    System.out.println("NO ERRORS!");
else
    System.out.println("SOME ERRORS!");
```

Comment: Well this is embarrassing! But trying this out, I have an empty file (absolutely empty - no spaces, no new lines) - but the byte count is 255 bytes. My guess is, it could because of the BOM field for Unicode. So this method doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use `file.length == 0`.

It is sometimes possible that the first line is empty.