# Workaround java.io.EOFException cause by ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, oop, objectinputstream, eofexception

For my application I want to use a Map to act as a database. To save and load a map, I am writing/reading it to/from database.ser using this 2 methods:

```
private synchronized void saveDB() {
    try {
        fileOut = new FileOutputStream(db);
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
        out.writeObject(accounts);
        fileOut.close();
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void loadDB() {
    try {
        fileIn = new FileInputStream(db);
        in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn); // that is where error is produced if fileIn is empty
        accounts = (Map<String, Client>) in.readObject();
        in.close();
        fileIn.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I want to load into Map when application starts, so I invoke method in constructor like this:

```
protected DriveatorImpl() {
    accounts = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Client>();
    db = new File("C:/Users/eduar/git/Multy-Threaded-Bank-System/Bank-Services/database.ser"); 
// also, any suggestions how can I make path to a file more flexible in case I want to run Server side of an app on different machine?
     if (!db.exists()) {
        try {
            db.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
    loadDB(); // loads database when server start 
}
```

I am aware of what causing an error, but I don't know what should I change in my design to avoid ObjectInputStream constructor receiving empty stream! 
Any suggestions on what I can do differently?

Edit: I want to note that in fresh application run database.ser is empty since there was no entries made into Map yet.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First why the EOFExcpetion occur?

1. There are no contents in file or file is empty and you tried to read file.

   - You can avoid the EOFException for an empty file by checking file content length if it is less than or equal to zero means file is empty. [another way to check if file is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281370/see-if-file-is-empty)

Some code change and it worked for me.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void loadDB() {
    try {
        if (db.length() <= 0) {
            // if statement evaluates to true even if file doesn't exists
            saveDB(); // save to a file an empty map
                      // if file doesn't exist, it creates a new one 
                      // call loadDB inside constructor

        }
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(db);
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn); // that is where error is produced if fileIn is empty
        in.readObject();
        in.close();
        fileIn.close();
        System.out.println(accounts);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't make head or tail of #2, and the second bullet point is equally meaningless. Your 'another way' is exactly the same as your original way of checking for emptiness.

Comment: I think checking for empty file and returning from method is exactly what I needed! I am calling saveDB() in methods where I am putting or modifying values in map to insure all data is saved in case server crashes. I think I understand now why calling saveDB() method in constructor before loadDB() would work. It writes to a file an empty map, but still some bytes going through the stream. Only problem is, if I have some values already stored in Map and I save it to a file, subsequent instantiation of a class will overwrite file with empty map and all data will be lost. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. Please try to avoid the duplicate question as @EJP mentioned. It will help to avoid mess up. Thank you.

Comment: I don't agree with @EJP that question is duplicated. Last question was about path to a file and File Not Found Exception. An additional error was revealed during a review that cause EOFExcpetion and has to do with empty stream being passed to an ObjectInputStream constructor. I think this question requires individual attention.

Comment: @GarRudo Please tick to the answer I have submitted for your problem so that, other people can see that, this solved your issue. Thank you.

Comment: Fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `file.exists()/file.createNewFile()` crap. All it is doing for you is masking the original `FileNotFoundException` problem, and turning into a thoroughly predictable `EOFException` because of trying to construct an `ObjectInputStream` around an empty stream. Handle the *original* problem. Don't just move it, or turn it into something else.

Comment: I understand now when read your comment to original post. This would be a graceful solution I need. Thank you.