# How to check if file content is empty

Tags: java, file, hadoop, mapreduce, bufferedreader

I am trying to check if a file content is empty or not. I have a source file where the content is empty.
I tried different alternatives.But nothing is working for me.

Here is my code:

```
  Path in = new Path(source);
    /*
     * Check if source is empty
     */
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(in)));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        if (br.readLine().length() == 0) {
            /*
             * Empty file
             */
            System.out.println("In empty");
            System.exit(0);

        }
        else{
            System.out.println("not empty");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

I have tried using -

```
1. br.readLine().length() == 0
2. br.readLine() == null
3. br.readLine().isEmpty()
```

All of the above is giving as not empty.And I need to use -

```
BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(in)));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Instead of new File() etc.

Please advice if I went wrong somewhere.

EDIT

> Making little more clear. If I have a file with just whitespaces or
>   without white space,I am expecting my result as empty.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190618/most-efficient-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-empty-in-java-on-windows

Comment: @UnknownOctopus: Yes I checked that too. But it is not working . I have to use new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(in))); also . I dont want to use new File()

Comment: What is the output of `System.out.println(">" + br.readline() + "<");`?

Comment: @Sleafar : Output :
 not empty
>null<
using the above mentioned code( if (br.readLine().length() == 0) {)

Comment: Why don't you want to use `new File()`? reading the file is much more expensive than just looking at it with `new File()`

Comment: @Barnash: This is  a code snippet from my mapreduce job, In mapreduce new File wont work as we expect

Comment: @UnmeshaSreeVeni ok, well, Writing a different answer

Comment: @UnmeshaSreeVeni Then checking for `null` should have worked, odd.

Comment: @Sleafar :  No that too didnt worked. I was also expecting the same,My tought was it will work.Once tested it is not working

Answer (score 9):

You could call [`File.length()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29) (which *Returns the length of the file denoted by this abstract pathname*) and check that it isn't `0`. Something like

```
File f = new File(source);
if (f.isFile()) {
    long size = f.length();
    if (size != 0) {

    }
}
```

#### To ignore white-space (as also being *empty*)

You could use [`Files.readAllLines(Path)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-) and something like

```
static boolean isEmptyFile(String source) {
    try {
        for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(source))) {
            if (line != null && !line.trim().isEmpty()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Default to true.
    return true;
}
```

Comment: even tough my file is empty.It is showing there is content using all of these code.I am still wondering

Comment: Is empty length of 0 bytes, or is white space also "empty'?

Comment: even if my file contains just whitespaces or 0 bytes it should show file is empty. My file contains white space

Comment: Edit your question to include that little detail. Be aware you may have to read the entire file to determine emptiness with that definition. A million spaces is empty, a million spaces followed by a letter 'a' isn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("myfile.txt");
if (is.read() == -1) {
    // The file is empty!
} else {
    // The file is NOT empty!
}
```

Of course you will need to close the `is` and catch `IOException`

Comment: That should not happen. Since the first read should return the first byte value in the file (which will be values from 0 to 255), if it returns -1 it means the read has ended

Comment: is.read is returning an integer. and I included them in if else.  could you please edit your answer by including if else

Comment: Yes with the same code I am getting it as not empty.It is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

**A Utility class to handle the isEmptyFile check**

```
package com.stackoverflow.answers.mapreduce;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

public class HDFSOperations {

    private HDFSOperations() {}

    public static boolean isEmptyFile(Configuration configuration, Path filePath)
            throws IOException {
        FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(configuration);
        if (hasNoLength(fileSystem, filePath))
            return false;
        return isEmptyFile(fileSystem, filePath);
    }

    public static boolean isEmptyFile(FileSystem fileSystem, Path filePath)
            throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(fileSystem.open(filePath)));
        String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            if (isNotWhitespace(line))
                return false;
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean hasNoLength(FileSystem fileSystem, Path filePath)
            throws IOException {
        return fileSystem.getFileStatus(filePath).getLen() == 0;
    }

    public static boolean isWhitespace(String str) {
        if (str == null) {
            return false;
        }
        int length = str.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if ((Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(i)) == false)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean isNotWhitespace(String str) {
        return !isWhitespace(str);
    }

}
```

**Class to test the Utility**

```
package com.stackoverflow.answers.mapreduce;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

public class HDFSOperationsTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "D:/tmp/source/expected.txt";
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            Path filePath = new Path(fileName);
            System.out.println("isEmptyFile: "
                    + HDFSOperations.isEmptyFile(configuration, filePath));
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If my file is empty,It is not showing file empty.and If I  am having white spaces in file then ,It is showing file is empty