# Java: UTF-8 and BOM

Tags: java, utf-8, byte-order-mark

On a page of Java's Bug Database https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4508058 it reads that Sun/Oracle will not fix the problem of Java not parsing the BOM of a UTF-8-encoded string. Since the most recent comment on this page dates back to 2010, I would like to know if there is any younger info about that? Is it still true that Java cannot handle BOM of UTF-8?

Comment: I disagree with how how you have stated the issue, but yes: the Java encoder and decoder for UTF-8 of course makes no allowance for a  superfluous BOM. BOMs on UTF-8 are really bad news, and break all kinds of things.  Please never use them; if you find yourself needing to specify the file encodings, then use a higher level protocol, such as MIME headers, an embedded declaration or comment in whatever programming language it is, or via the customary file extension “.utf8”.

Comment: I agree with you. However, if you want to create a UTF-8 csv file that users can open directly in Excel, then there is no way around BOM. If you don't use a BOM, it will read it as an ANSI file. (Microsoft should be sued for all the development hours their BOM has cost the world)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is still true that Java cannot handle the BOM in UTF8 encoded files. I came across this issue when parsing several XML files for data formatting purposes. Since you can't know when you might come across them, I would suggest stripping the BOM marker out if you find it at runtime or following the advice that tchrist gave.

Comment: If you're at a loss about how to do that: a quick way is `if (text.codePointAt(0) == 0xfeff) text = text.substring(1, text.length());` (this will also catch the UTF-8 BOM `EF BB BF`). A more elaborate approach is described at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835430/byte-order-mark-screws-up-file-reading-in-java/1835529#1835529