# java encoding issue while reading stream

Tags: java, encoding, ftp

I am trying to download contents from ftp folder. There is one xml file which starts with standardazed xml codes.

```
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

when i read these files (using java.net.Socket)and get input stream and then try to convert to String, somehow i get some new charecters. And the whole xml document starts with '?' eg. "?< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>....."

```
BufferedInputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
```

Then i  am getting a string from this reader using following code.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

String line;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(reader));

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
}
System.out.println ("sb.toString()");
```

Not sure whats happening here. why am i getting some special charecters introduced ?Any suggestions would be appreciated

and then i just used following code to read the file and in console i see some special charecters

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new     FileReader("c:/Users/appd922/DocumentMeta06122014.xml"));
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
sb.append(line);
}

String output = sb.toString();
System.out.println("reading from file"+output);
```

I got output starting 
"reading from fileï»¿< ?xml version.....

where am i getting these special charecters ?

Note- ignore the space in the xml file line given above. i could not write here with proper xmlwithout that space.

Comment: If the file had been correctly read using the UTF-8 encoding, those first three bytes would be read as a single [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) character, '\ufeff', a special Unicode character specifically intended to be the first character in a text document, where software can use it to determine the overall encoding of the document (including the byte order, if UTF-16 or UTF-32 is used).  In your case, it is showing up as the three characters "ï»¿" because your use of FileReader uses your system's default charset, which assumes each byte is one character.

Comment: Is it appropriate to include the BOM in an xml document with the prolog present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those characters are called BOM, Byte Order Mark. If you set the encoding of the `InputStreamReader` to 'UTF-8', you could see that they are interpreted as a single character, that is the BOM character.

Unfortunately, you have to handle this character yourself, because Java won't do it for you: [java utf-8 and bom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876111/java-utf-8-and-bom). Usually you just strip your stream of it. Good luck.

Comment: yes , i had to handle in code for BOM,  i removed this charecter - "\uFEFF" . and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Specify the encoding when creating `InputStreamReader` to read the file from the ftp, for example:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(reader, "utf-8"));
```

Otherwise, `InputStreamReader` uses default encoding. Also, specify the encoding when reading the downloaded file. `FileReader` uses default platform encoding. Use `InputStreamReader` and specify encoding, for example:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath), "utf-8"));
```