# How to clean up byte character like ÿþ?

Tags: scala

I was using Scala and try to store some String Integer as straight Integer. However some String Integer has a format of this `ÿþ` in front of the number.

How do I clean this up? Why does this happen?

---

Rephrased question:

How do I check all characters like `ÿþ`and delete them so I can safely convert Strings to Integer? I don't know if this appears only on the first line or not. The file has 16,000 lines and although I only see it at the first line so far, I can't be sure.

Comment: "I don't know if this appears only on the first line or not. The file has 16,000 lines and although I only see it at the first line so far, I can't be sure." - It's only 16000 lines. Check! Just load it into notepad...

Comment: @Paul OK..it turns out to be an encoding problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two are the [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) of UTF-16.

You could use [the tools from Apache Commons IO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7390288/1907906).

Comment: means it's words like `ÿþ123123123`

Comment: It's Integer but since it's read from a file, the format is String

Comment: Does only the first line of such a file contain the BOM?

Comment: That's the question..I don't know. The file has 16,000 lines.

Comment: @WindDweller rephrased question -- *does only the first integer that you read prefixed with such characters*? Rephrased top answer is *It's a special character used to signify use of particular scheme of data storing (UTF-16) -- there are libraries that allow you to read file with specifying that scheme, instead of relying on default one, so character will be swallowed and data will be read fully properly*

Comment: Very nice rephrasing, indeed.

Comment: @om-nom-nom I was trying out `ISO` or `Windows format`, which are not working at all.