# Java IO fails to read text file

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner

when I try to read thesaurus.txt, it reads it as "ÿþ ", although the first entry is "`<pat>a cappella`". What could be causing this?

```
    File file = new File("thesaurus.txt");
    Scanner scan;
    try {
        scan = new Scanner(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        scan = null;
    }
    String entry;
    ArrayList<String> thes = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(scan.hasNext())
    {
        entry = scan.nextLine();
        if(entry != "")
        {
             thes.add(entry);
        }
    }
    return thes;
```

Comment: I tested the code and it works for me. My only guess would be that the file has a different character encoding than expected.

Comment: I agree with Johan.  Sounds like an encoding issue.  Try forcing a specific encoding. If you don't know what character encoding is, google it.  "ASCII" and "UTF-8" are some examples.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22763251/1544337

Comment: Switching to ASCII worked, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Yout input file is probably an UTF-16 (LE) file that starts with a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

If you look at this file as if it is [ISO 8859-1](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1) you'll see those two characters: ÿþ which have codes `FF` and `FE` in that character encoding, which are exactly what you would expect when there's a UTF-16 BOM present.

You should explicitly specify the character encoding when reading the file, instead of relying on the default character encoding of your system:

```
scan = new Scanner(file, "UTF-16");
```