# java utils.Properties how to ignore BOM char

Tags: java, utf-8, properties, java-6

I edit in notepad cfg.prop file

cfg.prop:

key=val

```
my code:
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("etc/agent.prop"), "UTF-8"));
    System.out.println(prop);
```

then I see in stdout {?key=val}, becose notepad save UTF-8 file with BOM character (efbbbf)
how to ignore this character?
I use java6u21

Comment: possible duplicate of [Byte order mark screws up file reading in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835430/byte-order-mark-screws-up-file-reading-in-java)

Comment: I solved it just add new line in the beginning. Who knows cleaner solution