# Handle BOM in JAXB unmarshaller

Tags: jaxb, byte-order-mark

How can JAXB handle a string (of XML) that starts with a BOM? Is there a property to set or some configuration to skip the BOM when unmarshalling?Are there other JAXB implementations that could do that beside Oracle's implementation?

Answer (score 3):

If you're referring to a UTF-8 file with a BOM, then you will have to skip it yourself. It's fairly simple to come up with an InputStream class that checks the first two bytes for a BOM and skips them and otherwise wraps another InputStream. This has been documented in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835430/byte-order-mark-screws-up-file-reading-in-java) and open source code for this purpose is available [from GitHub](https://github.com/gpakosz/UnicodeBOMInputStream).

If you're referring to some other encoding like UTF-16, the JRE should read the BOM from a UTF-16 stream and discard it itself.

Comment: I have a string that is an xml content , something like this '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> ....' and I create a StringReader to read the content into unmarshaller like this: unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml)); but the string start with a BOM and here came the problem since the unmarshalling process crash, I thought JAXB has some property to set up and handle by it self the BOM char without any changes from me.

Comment: No, you still have to do it yourself, sadly. May I also call your attention to the [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) project, especially the [BOMInputStream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/input/BOMInputStream.html) and/or the [XmlStreamReader](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/input/XmlStreamReader.html) classes?

Comment: yes, I'll have to take a look into that classes, thanks a lot for your help ;).