# append unwanted character while reading xml file in java

Tags: java, xml

I have facing issue while reading xml file.
At the start of file it will append unwanted character..like ï»؟<
xml file is like 25000 lines
I used below code..

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("XXXXX.xml"));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                //System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                sb.append(sCurrentLine);
            }
```

Please help to solve this. How can I remove unwanted character?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Byte order mark screws up file reading in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835430/byte-order-mark-screws-up-file-reading-in-java)

Comment: thanks for reply it append character like ? <  how to avoid this?

Comment: Please show how you are initializing sb.  Are you passing an argument to the constructor?