# Java.Nio - ByteBuffer give weird character in json string type message

Tags: java, json, multithreading, client-server, nio

I have Java Client-Server application I built using standard java.io (Socket and ServerSocket). In both server and client, I use `DataInputStream` to read the message using `readUTF` and `DataOutputStream` to write the message using `writeUTF`. I use thread-per-connection architecture for this application.

I have an additional feature that I need to add now, which is allowing a client to have a persistent connection open to the server and always listening to what server will write. I found out, with my current `thread-per-connection` architecture, my application won't scale because it holds the thread when the client opens the persistent connection.

I did some research and think to refactor my server to use java.nio (SocketChannel and ServerSocketChannel). I try to make it compatible with the client (so I don't need to change the client). This is when the problem occurs because I need to change from `readUTF` method to using `ByteBuffer` class to read the message, now I got a weird character in my message.

This is my message that works before using `readUTF` (Server) that come from `writeUTF` (Client)
`{"command":"PUBLISH","resource":{"name":"","description":"","tags":[]}`

When I sent the same message to my new server, I got this in my read method
`�{"command":"PUBLISH","resource":{"name":"","description":"","tags":[]}`

My read method is:

```
else if (clientKey.isReadable()) {
    SocketChannel clientSocket = (SocketChannel) clientKey.channel();
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4096);
    clientSocket.read(buffer);
    String message = new String(buffer.array());
    Logger.debug(message);
    clientSocket.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
}
```

This is how I write the message from client:

```
try (Socket echoSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
     DataOutputStream streamOut = new DataOutputStream(echoSocket.getOutputStream());) {
        streamOut.writeUTF(message.toJson());
}
```

`toJson()` is just a method to convert java object to JSON string and I use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) library to do that.

I have tried to remove it using regex and `Normalizer` library but it won't work.

Is there anyone experience the same things and solve it?

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835430/byte-order-mark-screws-up-file-reading-in-java

Comment: It doesn't work, because the read process is blocking operation, and it won't work with java.nio when you set blocking = false

Comment: i suggest u show us the write method too?

Comment: updated with how I send the message from client