# How to remove byte order mark using scala.io.Source?

Tags: java, scala, io, byte-order-mark

[Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) is making my regex fail when using `scala.io.Source` to read from a file. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1835529/8762739) is a lightweight solution using `java.io`. Is there anything similar for `scala.io.Source`, or will I have to revert back to Java because of a *single* byte?

Comment: Could you just use `Source.fromInputStream` to wrap one of the answers from the linked question?

Answer (score 1):

Based on Joe K's idea in his comment, and using [Andrei Punko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18275066/8762739) for the problem in Java and [Alvin Alexander's Scala code](https://alvinalexander.com/source-code/scala-java-bufferedreader-readline-while-loop-boolean), the simplest solution to read a file possibly containing byte order mark into an array of string is:

```
@throws[IOException]
def skip(reader: Reader): Unit = {
    reader.mark(1)
    val possibleBOM = new Array[Char](1)
    reader.read(possibleBOM)
    if (possibleBOM(0) != '\ufeff') reader.reset
}

val br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)))
skip(br)

val lines = {
    val ls = new ArrayBuffer[String]()
    var l: String = null
    while ({l= br.readLine; l != null}) {
      ls.append(l)
    }
    br.close
    ls.toArray
}
```