# Parsing XHTML with java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, xhtml

I need a little guidance with reading from a URL XHTML page in java:

Here's my best try to print a specific String:

```
    try {       
    URL item = new URL("url");
                URLConnection connect = item.openConnection();
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc= dBuilder.parse(connect.getInputStream());
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("tag");
                for(int temp = 0; temp<nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                    if(nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        Element el = (Element) nNode;
        System.out.println((el.getElementsByTagName("wantedElement").item(0).getTextContent()));
                    }}
}catch(IOException | ParserConfigurationException | SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Response from Eclipse:

```
 [Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

XHTML sample I'm trying to parse (from TD Ameritrade API):

```
<CandleList>
<candles>
<candles>
<open>45.97</open>
<high>46.26</high>
<low>45.8</low>
<close>46.0</close>
<volume>7176781</volume>
<datetime>1496293200000</datetime>
</candles>
<candles>
<open>46.22</open>
<high>46.86</high>
<low>45.9</low>
<close>46.8</close>
<volume>9523927</volume>
<datetime>1496379600000</datetime>
</candles>
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: how about posting what text you are trying to parse

Comment: If your XML's indentation is as messy as your code snippet's is, I have a clue about what causes the error :)

Comment: I wouldn't try parse XHTML pulled from some web site with the DOM API. Use jsoup instead. It's more forgiving.

Comment: Posted text I'm trying to parse - sorry. Will try JSOUP. Thanks

Comment: What you’re parsing is not XHTML but XML. And you need to post the whole response including the first few characters because that’s where the problem is (you also need to post the end because the xml you’ve posted is invalid because it doesn’t close all tags)

Comment: If you try to validate this *xml* using https://www.xmlvalidation.com/ it also fails

Comment: I'm interested in the `catch(IOException | ParserConfigurationException | SAXException e)` bit. Can Java really do that? Maybe I should have kept up with the versions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while the question has all the issues mentioned in the comment, the error at line 1 column 1 is about BOM at the beginning of the stream.

Some services, especially .Net services send BOM at the beginning of the stream to mark the encoding, like UTF-8, UTF-16LE etc.

[Byte order mark screws up file reading in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835430/byte-order-mark-screws-up-file-reading-in-java/1835529#1835529)