# Integer.Parse throws NumberFormatException on excel fetched String

Tags: java, excel

in my program I fetch each line of an Excel table. When I split the line, in order to parse each `String` of the array to an `Integer`, the Exception mentioned in the title gets thrown. The table is populated in this way:

```
0;1;100;4;1000;8;8
...
```

The table is saved as `.csv`that's why I split by `;`

**Idea: File values contain false chars:**
I already checked for 0-width characters...

**Code snippet:**

```
try {
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(flag == 0){
                tableSize = line.split(";").length;
                System.out.println("TableSize is: "+tableSize);
                flag = 1;
                table1 = new int[tableSize][tableSize];
            }
            String [] tempStrings = line.split(";");
            int [] tempInts = new int[tableSize];

            for(int i=0; i<tableSize;i++){
                tempInts[i] = Integer.parseInt(tempStrings[i]);
                System.out.println(tempInts[i]);
            }

            table1[row] = tempInts;
            row++;
        }
```

Any help is highly appreciated!
**Edit:** After creating a new .csv file same problem
**Stacktrace of the NumberFormatException**:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at excercise.Main.fillTableByCsv(Main.java:53)
at excercise.Main.main(Main.java:22)
```

Comment: Try - catch the exception and print the string in  catch { }

Comment: The String printed is "0"

Comment: @Alan, meaning exception message reads `For input string: "0"`? Are you sure it's zero and not an O?

Comment: Yes I checked it (and replaced it)

Comment: `Integer.parseInt("0")` is never going to throw an exception. There must be spurious characters in some string, or a string is empty, or something.

Comment: I created another File: Same problem always throws the exception

Comment: Would you mind post the complete stacktrace? And if you can, make your file available for us

Comment: @ngueno stacktrace added, where can i upload the file for you?

Comment: @Alan You can use any drive you have access or share permissions :)

Comment: @ngueno is weTransfer ok?

Comment: If yes here is the download link of my table: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/fd7ad5a8e5100e0aac2439690111ddcb20190211193643/03b5ef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSV file begins with a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) encoded in UTF-8. You can see it, for example, if you open the file in a hex editor:

[image]

Although the extra bytes EF BB BF are not visible, they are what's upsetting `Integer.parseInt`.

See [Byte order mark screws up file reading in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835430/byte-order-mark-screws-up-file-reading-in-java) for some solutions.