# OpenCSV CsvToBean: First column not read for UTF-8 Without BOM

Tags: java, csv, utf-8, character-encoding, opencsv

Using OpenCSV to parse UTF-8 documents **without** BOM results in the first column not read. Giving as an input the same document content but encoded in UTF-8 **with** BOM works correctly.

I set specifically the charset to UTF-8

```
    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
    HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<Bean> ms = new HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<Bean>();
    ms.setType(Bean.class);
    CsvToBean<Bean> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder<Bean>(reader).withType(Bean.class).withMappingStrategy(ms)
            .withSeparator(';').build();
    csvToBean.parse();
```

I've created a sample project where the issue can be reproduced: 
https://github.com/dajoropo/csv2beanSample

Running the Unit Test you can see how the UTF-8 file without BOM fails and with BOM works correctly.

The error comes in the second assertion, because the first column in not read. Result it:

*[Bean [a=**null**, b=second, c=third]]*

Any hint?

Comment: What assertion fails - number of parsed lines or it is not equal to "first" (so what is it?)?

Comment: Also, OpenCSV is open source. You have small test which reproduces problem - just walk-through with a debugger and check what's wrong

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov the question is now updated specifying the error. I've tried debugging OpenCSV. I've seen that the first column is written wrongly in the fieldMap inside HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy = [ ,A] instead of [A]. But I don't know why this happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I open `Bean` class in you project and search for "B" then I can find one entry. If I search for "A" then I cannot :) It means you copy/pasted A with BOM header to `Bean` class. BOM header is not visible but still taken into account.

If I fix "A" then another test starts failing but I think you can fix it using  `BOMInputStream`.

Check this question and answer [Byte order mark screws up file reading in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835430/byte-order-mark-screws-up-file-reading-in-java)

It is known problem. You can use Apache Commons IO's `BOMInputStream` to solve it.

Just tried

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

and

```
        inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(new BOMInputStream(fileInputStream), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

and fixing

```
@CsvBindByName(column = "A")
private String a;
```

to exclude prefix from "A" makes both tests passing

Comment: Thanks for this input! Seems to be a great library, but I can't make any difference with it. I've tried creating a BOMInputStream bomIn = new BOMInputStream(fileInputStream); and giving it as parameter to the InputStreamReader. I tried giving the BOM type or saying exclude or include, and also making bomIn.read() to skip the BOM... Nothing worked. One point that is maybe not clear: I have the issues reading when there is no BOM. Usually the problems are when a BOM is present. This is why I didn't find any answer so far that works.

Comment: I re-wrote answer. You have to fix typo in your code + use `BOMInputStream`

Comment: Crazy issue... Thank you very much!