# DOM parsing with UTF-8 XML files

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I'm using Primefaces `<p:fileUpload>` component for file selection by users. 
In that, I'm using the `fileUploadListener` attribute that uses a custom method to read XML files and parse them using `DOMParser`. My file reading and parsing code boils down to this much:

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\test\\test_ansi.xml");
Reader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
InputSource is = new InputSource(new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader));
DOMParser parser = new DOMParser();
parser.parse(is);
Document doc = parser.getDocument();
```

I have a need to convert all user-selected XMLs to UTF-8 before processing them further.
If I try the above code with a file encoded as ANSI, it works fine. But if the file is encoded as UTF-8, I'm getting the below error:

```
oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Start of root element expected.
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLError.flushErrors(XMLError.java:233)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLError.error(XMLError.java:133)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLError.error(XMLError.java:171)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseRootElement(NonValidatingParser.java:280)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseDocument(NonValidatingParser.java:241)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:124)
```

For sample UTF-8 files, I'm just saving the file with encoding as UTF-8 in Notepad.
Can anyone please help me understand what's going wrong?

Comment: Please, provide the content of test_ansi.xml file.

Comment: @olgacosta It's this much: 
`<Vehicles>
 <vehicle>
  <name>car</name>
  <wheels>4</wheels>
 </vehicle>
 <vehicle>
  <name>bike</name>
  <wheels>2</wheels>
 </vehicle>
</Vehicles>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like encoded as UTF-8 file contains [Unicode BOM character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning and that's why the parsing fails.

You can wrap FileInputStream using [BOMInputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.2/org/apache/commons/io/input/BOMInputStream.html) like this

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\test\\test_ansi.xml");
BOMInputStream bomInputStream = new BOMInputStream(inputStream, false);
Reader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(bomInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

[It constructs a new BOM InputStream that detects a ByteOrderMark.UTF_8 and excludes it.](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.2/org/apache/commons/io/input/BOMInputStream.html#BOMInputStream(java.io.InputStream,%20boolean))

Please, find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835430/byte-order-mark-screws-up-file-reading-in-java).