# What is Java's equivalent of Windows Notepad "Unicode Encoding"?

Tags: java, excel, unicode, encoding, notepad

I have tab-separated values which I need to export as a text file using Java, to be opened in Microsoft Excel. The problem arises when the tab-separated values have Chinese characters.

I tried exporting the text file using UTF-8 but Excel is not able to interpret the characters. Then I opened the exported text file in Notepad and saved it as "Unicode" and it started showing the correct charters in Excel.

[image]

So can someone tell me what is the Notepad "Unicode" equivalent in Java?

My code is:

```
response.getOutputStream().write(reportHTML.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Where reportHTML has tab-separated values.

[This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5glcrjr5b27opwu/AccumGradebookRpt.txt) is the text file with encoding as Unicode.

Comment: Look at the file in a hex editor and determine whether it's UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32

Comment: @jlordo Can you please suggest a hex editor and how to check encoding. I have also linked the correct text file which works correctly in excel

Comment: Notepad++ tells me your File is in UCS-2 Little Endian. [Here is a List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html) of all supported encodings.

Comment: @jlordo I don't see UCS-2 Little Endian in the list you provided, so this means we cannot do this using java?

Comment: Excel should be able to handle UTF-8 (might need BOM, but don't think so), maybe you have an error in your implemantation. You could use UTF-16, read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) to see the difference to UCS-2.

Comment: Excel is not able to handle UTF-8 you can check that by downloading the linked text file, opening it in notepad and then saving it as "UTF-8"

Comment: Don't have Excel atm. Your File is not UTF-8, even though your code should produce an UTF-8 file. Save your file as UTF-8 (when writing t, not in Notepad), not UCS-2 and when importing in Excel there is an option to specify the charset of the imported file. UTF-8 is in that list.

Comment: @jlordo this is the UTF-8 file after adding bom as suggested by Dmitry Kurilo https://dl.dropbox.com/u/99923120/stackoverflow/AccumGradebookRpt%20%281%29.txt. It shows me chinese characters but it messes with the tabs in Excel

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20239/discussion-between-jlordo-and-ankur)

Comment: Just one word to add: http://utf8everywhere.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means `"UTF-16LE"`, and every java platform implementation is [required](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) to support it.

```
response.getOutputStream().write(reportHTML.getBytes("UTF-16LE"));
```

The notepad unicode encoding also inserts the UTF-16LE BOM `FF FE` at the start of the file.

Comment: this is the file generated in UTF-16LE https://dl.dropbox.com/u/99923120/stackoverflow/AccumGradebookRpt%20%282%29.txt and this is the snap of how it opens in excel https://dl.dropbox.com/u/99923120/stackoverflow/excel%20snap%20utf-16.png

Comment: @Ankur the text file you gave me is either encoded in UTF-32LE or double encoded UTF-16. At closer inspection it looks like it's double encoded UTF-16 because of sequences like `4E005300`. Try a simple test like writing `"ääöö".getBytes("UTF-16LE")` to a file and see if it works

Comment: I tried the code you gave me and this is the content type `"text/plain; charset=utf-16le"`

Comment: @Ankur the content type doesn't matter in this case, as I said, the file is incorrectly double encoded in utf16. Try the simple test I suggested and you'll see there is a mistake in your code somewhere that causes double encoding.

Comment: I tried "ääöö".getBytes("UTF-16LE") but it doesn't work. This is the code `return "ääööhajsgagdasfdjhDNJDSHFJHDJ".getBytes("UTF-16LE");` andf this is the text file https://dl.dropbox.com/u/99923120/stackoverflow/AccumGradebookRpt%20%286%29.txt

Comment: @Ankur what does that give? Look at the bytes of the file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20245/discussion-between-ankur-and-esailija)

Answer (score 0):

Try add BOM to first byte of file. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: I tried adding BOM for UTF-16LE using http://stackoverflow.com/a/713255/662250 but instead of adding `FF FE` it adds `OA 00 00 00`

Comment: Can you add manually?

The UTF-8 representation of the BOM is the byte sequence 0xEF,0xBB,0xBF

Comment: I did as you said and it worked and exported the text file as UTF-8, but then it started messing with the tab characters, Here is the link to the exported file https://dl.dropbox.com/u/99923120/stackoverflow/AccumGradebookRpt%20%281%29.txt

Answer (score 0):

In a Windows environment, when an encoding is called "Unicode" then it *usually* refers to [UCS-2 or UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).

Comment: I tried UCS-2 and it says `java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: UCS-2` and UTF-16 doesn't give me the desired result

Comment: In Notepad, “Unicode” means specifically little-endian UTF-16, UTF-16LE.

Comment: this is the file generated in UTF-16LE https://dl.dropbox.com/u/99923120/stackoverflow/AccumGradebookRpt%20%282%29.txt and this is the snap of how it opens in excel https://dl.dropbox.com/u/99923120/stackoverflow/excel%20snap%20utf-16.png

Comment: So the `&agrave;` is your problem? Then it's not an encoding problem at all! You're CSV contains HTML/XML character references, which are not known/understood outside of HTML/XML! That's quite a different topic altogether! We could have avoided this long-winded problem-finding if you had described the error behaviour in more detail in the beginning.