# How can I get national signs (UTF-8) displayed properly when read from external text file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, utf-8

As title indicates. I get a txt file and convert it to web content. The problem is it doesn't display diacritic signs, like o with dash over it or z with dot over. Charset is set to utf-8, language to "pl" and normally there was never any problems.

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="button">Display data</button>
    <div id="show">
    </div>
    <script>

    const data = [];
    const single = [];
    const button = document.querySelector("#button");
    const show = document.querySelector("#show");

    fetch('data.txt')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => data.push(text));

    function display() {
      const allOfThem = data[0].split("\r"); 
      allOfThem.forEach((person) => {
        let newP = document.createElement("p");
        newP.innerHTML = "Person's data:  " + person;
        show.appendChild(newP);
      })
    }

    button.addEventListener("click", display);
    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: Most likely the textfile itself is not utf-8 encoded. You've to save the file as utf-8 encoded.

Comment: National signs? language to "pl"?

Comment: "*Charset is set to utf-8*"? Where did you do that, in the HTTP header? And the content is actually utf-8 as well?

Comment: First, what is the character encoding of the text file? Next, please show minimal code to read the file "and convert it to web content".

Comment: Text file is saved as unicode text document in Notepad.  Lang="pl" is attached to html <html lang="pl">.

Comment: Notepad as in Windows' ye olde notepad? "Unicode" in that context means UTF16LE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894898/unicode-file-in-notepad

Comment: What does the HTTP Content-Type response header say for 'data.txt'? )(Open browser dev tools using the F12 key or equiv.) I.E., how are you communicating its character encoding?

Answer (score 1):

Okay guys, thank you for help. 
You were right : neither notepad nor WordPad encode txt to utf-8. 
I created a txt file with Atom, copypasted the text and read from that.
And all characters are now as they should be.

Thank you, problem solved :)